# Split dictionary into individual columns in a df

Tags: pandas

I have the following `df` whose values are dictionaries:

```
                    tests
SO4  {'Mon': 6, 'Tues': 6, 'Wed': 7}
CH3  {'Mon': 0, 'Tues': 8, 'Wed': 10}
```

I would like to obtain the desired output :

```
         0        1          2
SO4  'Mon': 6 'Tues': 6 'Wed': 7
CH3  'Mon': 0 'Tues': 8 'Wed': 10
```

How could I split the dictionary into individual columns?

I have seen the columns split of strings using `rsplit` function but not sure on how to apply it in the case of dictionaries as values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think better is use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['tests'].values.tolist(), index=df.index)
print (df)
     Mon  Tues  Wed
SO4    6     6    7
CH3    0     8   10
```

But if really need it (but dicts are by design not sortable, so maybe get different output):

```
df = df['tests'].astype(str).str.strip('{}').str.split(', ', expand=True)
print (df)
            0          1          2
SO4  'Mon': 6   'Wed': 7  'Tues': 6
CH3  'Mon': 0  'Wed': 10  'Tues': 8
```

Comment: Yes, but very slow is use `apply(pd.Series)`, so rather not.

Comment: Yes, but a bit slowier. fatsest is `df['tests'].values.tolist()`

Comment: Ah, thanks, didn't realize that.