# How to flatten a JSON object within a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a nested JSON file to a dataframe. The dataframe now looks like this:

| product | shelfId |
| --- | --- |
| {'product': [{'id': '111', 'quantity': 10}]} | aaa |
| {'product': [{'id': '222', 'quantity': 0}]} | bbb |

Now I want to flatten the product column, and get a df like:

| productId | productQuantity | shelfId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 10 | aaa |
| 222 | 0 | bbb |

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: what is the output of `type(df.loc[0,'product'])`?

Comment: to be pedantic, that is not a JSON object. That is a Python `dict`

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131731/split-dictionary-into-individual-columns-in-a-df

Comment: ok, I see...Thanks!

Comment: I tried the other methods, df = pd.json_normalize(df['product']) and df = pd.DataFrame(df['product'].values.tolist(), index=df.index). But encountered another problem. I got empty dicts within the product column, something like: {'product': []}. And when splitting up, it will show 'list' object has no attribute 'values'. Is there a way to solve this? (sorry a bit new to pandas)

Answer (score 0):

I would apply a custom function to create a list of dict then convert to dataframe and add to old df.

```
def flatten(d):
    newd = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        for ik, iv in v.items():
            newd[f'{k}{ik.title()}'] = iv
    return newd

cols = pd.DataFrame([flatten(v) for v in df['product']])
df = df.concat([df, cols]).drop(columns=['product'])
```