# how to split dict column from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

- [Splitting dictionary/list inside a Pandas Column into Separate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/splitting-dictionary-list-inside-a-pandas-column-into-separate-columns/48266561#48266561)>

The  above link providing some solution to my answer

But i have same problem with little different in input. here my DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[[{'c':1},{'c':3}], {'d':3}, {'c':5, 'd':6}]})
```

My dict again contains list of dicts for Key "b".

My expected O/P :

```
  [a    c   c1    d 
0  1   1.0  3    NaN  
1  2   NaN  NaN  3.0 
2  3   5.0  NaN  6.0][1]
```

Could you please help.

Comment: it would be helpful to know what you've tried already. Also, what's with the `[1]` at the end of your dataframe?

Comment: DF1 = DF.loc[pd.notnull(DF.Modes)]["Modes"].apply(lambda x:                                                                                      pd.Series(eval(str(x))[0]))

user this operation. to split the dictionary, But only first dict is fetching i want all the list of dicts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
#convert to list of df with condition for add list
L = [pd.DataFrame(x) if isinstance(x, list) else pd.DataFrame([x]) for x in df['b']]
#join together, reshape and remove all NaNs columns
df1 = pd.concat(L, keys=df.index).unstack().dropna(how='all', axis=1)
#flattening MultiIndex in columns 
df1.columns = ['{}{}'.format(a,b) for a,b in df1.columns]
print (df1)
    c0   c1   d0
0  1.0  3.0  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  3.0
2  5.0  NaN  6.0

#remove original column b and join df1
df = df.drop('b',1).join(df1)
print (df)
   a   c0   c1   d0
0  1  1.0  3.0  NaN
1  2  NaN  NaN  3.0
2  3  5.0  NaN  6.0
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael,
This example is not working with my data.. Im reading the data from xls as data frame and applying your code.

Comment: Are data confidental?

Comment: No.. How to share my excel

Comment: Can you send me your code + file to my email from my profile? Thanks.

Comment: I send you email, can you check it?

Comment: i replied to your mail  jezrael

Comment: Please check answer. `df['Modes'] = df['Modes'].apply(pd.io.json.loads)`

Comment: my data is not always from xls file .. its a normal DF only.. pd.io is only applicable to some input file.. here my input from some data frame in code.

Comment: hmmm, source of data is not important, but if need convert `json` or `dict` column use `df['Modes'] = df['Modes'].apply(pd.io.json.loads)`.

Comment: facing below error.

  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2510, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1521, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
ValueError: Expected object or value

Comment: @RakeshBhagam - It means bad data, unfortunately :( You can check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48396555/2901002) for find all bad rows annd instaed `ast.literal_eval(x)` use `pd.io.json.loads(x)`

Comment: its return same DF only. 
Providing Input Again 
Input :
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[[{'x1':1,'x2':3},{'x1':4,'x2':1}],[{'x1':5},{'x1':3,'x2':6}]], 'c':[5,6]})

Expected Output : 
X1_0   x2_0     x1_1     x2_1
1           3            4              1
5        NaN         3              6

Comment: I add for you new answer. But in my opinion problem is with your data. What is source of your data? Excel, csv, json, some API? Because if source is file excel, csv there is problem your lists and dictionaries are converted to strings. So first step is converting from strings to dictionaries and lists and then is possible working with my solutions.

Comment: i understand now. with the new solution. my data is string while reading from .xls. 
Thanks Jezrael..

Comment: Yes, so how solution work? Or how working converting from strings to dictionaries?

Comment: I'm using  df[Column].apply(ast.literal_eval)  to read string and remaining same procedure.