# Converting list of dictionaries into single dictionary in python 3

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a snippet of data from which I need to extract specific information. The Data looks like this:

```
     pid      log     Date
     91      json     D1
     189     json     D2
     276     json     D3
     293     json     D4
     302     json     D5
     302     json     D6
     343     json     D7
```

The LOG is a json file stored in a column of an excel file which looks something like this:

```
{"Before":{"freq_term":"Daily","ideal_pmt":"246.03","datetime":"2015-01-08 06:26:11},"After":{"freq_term":"Bi-Monthly","ideal_pmt":"2583.33"}}

{"Before":{"freq_term":"Daily","ideal_pmt":"637.5","datetime":"2015-01-08 06:26:11"},"After":{"freq_term":"Weekly","ideal_pmt":"3346.88","datetime":"2015-02-02 06:16:07"}}

{"Before":{"buy_rate":"1.180","irr":"31.63","uwfee":"","freq_term":"Weekly"}, "After":{"freq_term":"Bi-Monthly","ideal_pmt":"2583.33"}}
```

Now, what I want is an output something like this:

```
    {
     "pid": 91,
     "Date": "2016-05-15 03:54:24"
    "Before": {
        "freq_term": "Daily"
        },
    "After": {
        "freq_term": "Weekly",

        }
}
```

Basically I want only the `"freq_term"` and `"Datetime"` of `"Before"` and `"After"` from the log file. So far I have done the following code. After this whatever I do it gives me the error: `list object is not callable`. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\dealChange.xlsx")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['pid', 'log', 'date']) 

li = df.to_dict('records')

dict(kv for d in li for kv in d.iteritems()) # error: list obj is not callable
```

How do I convert the list into a dictionary so that I can access only the data required..

Comment: `{"Before":"freq_term":"Daily"},`  - thats not really a valid dict in python? please reformat the desired output `{"pid": 91, {"Before":"freq_term":"Daily"},{"Date":"2015-01-08 06:26:11},"After":{"freq_term":"Bi-Monthly"},{"Date":"2015-01-18 06:30:11"}}` so its a valid result

Comment: I did. thanks for the correction. was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'log':['{"Before":{"freq_term":"Daily","ideal_pmt":"637.5","datetime":"2015-01-08 06:26:11"},"After":{"freq_term":"Weekly","ideal_pmt":"3346.88","datetime":"2015-02-02 06:16:07"}}','{"Before":{"buy_rate":"1.180","irr":"31.63","uwfee":"","freq_term":"Weekly"}, "After":{"freq_term":"Bi-Monthly","ideal_pmt":"2583.33"}}']})
print (df)
                                                 log
0  {"Before":{"freq_term":"Daily","ideal_pmt":"63...
1  {"Before":{"buy_rate":"1.180","irr":"31.63","u...
```

---

First convert values to nested `dictionaries` and then filter by nested dict comprehension:

```
df['log'] = df['log'].apply(pd.io.json.loads)

L1 = ['Before','After']
L2 = ['freq_term','datetime']
f = lambda x: {k:{k1:v1 for k1,v1 in v.items() if k1 in L2} for k,v in x.items() if k in L1}
df['new'] = df['log'].apply(f)
print (df)

                                                 log  \
0  {'After': {'ideal_pmt': '3346.88', 'freq_term'...   
1  {'After': {'ideal_pmt': '2583.33', 'freq_term'...   

                                                 new  
0  {'After': {'freq_term': 'Weekly', 'datetime': ...  
1  {'After': {'freq_term': 'Bi-Monthly'}, 'Before...
```

EDIT:

For find all rows with unparseable values is possible use:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(x)
    except:
        return 1

print (df[df['log'].apply(f) == 1])
```

Comment: Gives an error when i do `df['log'] = df['log'].apply(pd.io.json.loads)`. `ValueError: Expected object or value`. There are more than 10k values

Comment: If use `import ast`, `df['log'] = df1['log'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` how it working?

Comment: `ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x00000209C005C198>` when `df['log'] = df['log'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`. This works for a single row like: `ast.literal_eval(li[0]['log'])`

Comment: I think there is problem some bad data - e.g. some `"` missing :( e.g. in your sample in fiirst row is missing `"` in `"2015-01-08 06:26:11`

Comment: What I posted is edited. There is no problem in the actual data. Here there might be some typos but that can be corrected.

Comment: Hmmm, data are confidental?

Comment: `{"Before":{"freq_term":"Daily","ideal_pmt":"246.03","no_pmt":"252","datetime":"2015-03-05 04:51:07","auto_payment":"0"},"After":{"freq_term":"Bi-Monthly","ideal_pmt":"2583.33","no_pmt":"24","datetime":"2015-03-09 05:15:58","auto_payment":"1"}}` this is actual data for pid = 91. Similar for others

Comment: Yes, but problem is at least one typo in some row and solution failed :(

Comment: OMG there are more than 10k records. Damn. How will I find the error? But I dont think there is a typo. Can we go through one row at a time of the df that contains log? That way we can find the error. We could convert it into a list by 'li = df.to_dict('records')'

Comment: Ya, I have an idea, give me a sec.

Comment: Yes there are few records which are malformed. I will see how to workaround that. Will post soon.

Comment: Well, I checked it, and all are valid jsons. There is no malformed json in this.

Comment: OK, and still some problem? Solution failed? Are data confidental?

Comment: yeah, its not working. The data is good. I gave u sample of original data.

Comment: Solution not working - again failed in `df['log'] = df['log'].apply(pd.io.json.loads)` or `df['log'] = df['log'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` ? Or someting else?

Comment: yeah exactly. Can we convert the log into a dict using `ast.literal_eval()`? It works for a single record but not if I put it in a loop. OR we could write a regex to search for what is  needed in the log.

Comment: Are data confidental?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: Can you send me your file to my email in my profile?

Comment: sure I can, ur email?

Comment: I sent you. Please check.

Comment: OK, first `df['log'] = df['log'].apply(pd.io.json.loads)` working very nice, no error for me in python `3.5` under windows. But later I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: I need to achieve the output as I mentioned in the question. I'll try this once more.

Comment: Yes, do you get same error like me? Or still problem with `df['log'] = df['log'].apply(pd.io.json.loads)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163844/discussion-between-karan-gupta-and-jezrael).