# Searching and replacing in nested dictionary in a Pandas Dataframe column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Have some tricky situation. The Pandas Dataframe `df` contains a column `col` which has nested dictionaries as values looking like that:

```
{'code': 'D104',
  'description': 'Error Occured',
  'id': '5451235d',
  'root_cause': 'Brokage'}
```

What I need to do is to find the occurrences of certain codes in string and replace the whole string with it, in example above it will be searching for `'D104'` and all the string will be just `'D104'` instead of dict.

I tried to apply `.str.contains ()` on that column and use `replace ()` function on the column but it seems to be that the trick is not working with dictionaries as values. Can you please guide me the way?

Comment: Could you post what your output would look like for the example above?

Comment: I'm searching 'D104' in a column and the output is 'D104' instead of all the string which contains 'D104'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dictionaries have the same structure, you can [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/splitting-dictionary-list-inside-a-pandas-column-into-separate-columns) them into separate columns, and then work with those.

```
codes = df[col].apply(pd.Series)['code']
# add `codes` to `df` or lookup 'D104' in codes
...
```