# Add column of DataFrame based on a nested JSON in column

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas Dataframe (named `dx`):

```
                                    _id  user_type
0  {'$oid': '5b9058462f38434ab0d85cd3'}          1
1  {'$oid': '5b9058462f38434ab0d85ce9'}          1
2  {'$oid': '5b9058462f38434ab0d85ced'}          1
3  {'$oid': '5b9058462f38434ab0d85cee'}          1
4  {'$oid': '5b9058462f38434ab0d85cef'}          1
```

It came from a big JSON (more or less 500.000 rows and more columns then this example), as you can see the `_id` contain a nested JSON.

For this example, my target is to get a new column named `oid` with the *oid code*:

```
                                    _id  user_type                       oid
0  {'$oid': '5b9058462f38434ab0d85cd3'}          1  5b9058462f38434ab0d85cd3
1  {'$oid': '5b9058462f38434ab0d85ce9'}          1  5b9058462f38434ab0d85ce9
2  {'$oid': '5b9058462f38434ab0d85ced'}          1  5b9058462f38434ab0d85ced
3  {'$oid': '5b9058462f38434ab0d85cee'}          1  5b9058462f38434ab0d85cee
4  {'$oid': '5b9058462f38434ab0d85cef'}          1  5b9058462f38434ab0d85cef
```

I achieved the results using the following snippet:

```
dx['oid']=None
for i in dx.index:
     dx['oid'][i]=dx.at[i,'_id']['$oid']
```

This give me what I am looking for but it is very very slow. It takes 3-4 minutes to populate the column of the example, which has only 5 rows!

How can I optimize the creation of a new column based on other columns with JSON values?

I can't use regex because nested JSON is core complex then the one in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `object` column type which contain single `dict` within the cell so

```
df['$oid']=df['_id'].map(lambda x : x['$oid'])
```

Or

```
s=df['_id'].apply(pd.Series)
s
#df=pd.concat([df,s],axis=1)
Out[601]: 
                       $oid
0  5b9058462f38434ab0d85cd3
1  5b9058462f38434ab0d85ce9
2  5b9058462f38434ab0d85ced
3  5b9058462f38434ab0d85cee
4  5b9058462f38434ab0d85cef
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). No vectorised solution is possible since your input series has `object` dtype.

```
from operator import itemgetter

field_name = '$oid'
df[field_name] = list(map(itemgetter(field_name), df['_id']))
```

More generalised solutions are available, see [Splitting dictionary/list inside a Pandas Column into Separate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/splitting-dictionary-list-inside-a-pandas-column-into-separate-columns).