# How to make new columns from strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe, extract

I'm trying to split a column called "category" containing strings into two new columns "category" and "subcategory"

It's based on a kickstarter dataset we collected from webrobots.io. The "category" fields contain instances that look like this:

```py
In: frame.category[1]
Out: {"id":325,"name":"Calendars","slug":"publishing/calendars","position":4,"parent_id":18,"color":14867664,"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/publishing/calendars"}}}
```

I'm trying to get the first part of all rows after '"slug":"' before the slash (publishing) into a new column "category", and the part after slash before the quotation mark (calendars) into a new column "subcategory".
I've tried with str.split and str.extract and presume that extract is what i need, but I'm very new to regular expressions so all my attempts have failed

This is what I've tried for now, it just gives me two columns both containing NaN all the way through

```py
frame["category"].str.extract(r'(slug":")(/)')
```

It would be great if the result came out as two new columns with each one of the two words separated by the slash after "slug":"

***Edit:***
Thanks to Nev1111's idea of treating the column as its own dataframe and joris on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/splitting-dictionary-list-inside-a-pandas-column-into-separate-columns) I've come to the following code which works perfectly, although it might not be the best solution

```py
#Assigning 'category' to its own dataframe and reading it as a dictionary with each key as its own column
df=frame['category'].map(eval).apply(pd.Series)
#splitting "slug" and creating new columns based on the category and subcategory
frame[['category','subcategory']]=df['slug'].str.split('/',expand=True)
```

When printing "frame" i get the two new columns with category and subcategory

Comment: You can try [here](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Base on what you show to us , that columns is type is `object`--`dict`

```
frame["category"].str.get('slug')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, although I get an output, it just returns "NaN" throughout all the rows however.
```python
Out: 0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
5        NaN
6        NaN
7        NaN
8        NaN
9        NaN
10       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df=DataFrame( {"id":325,"name":"Calendars","slug":"publishing/calendars","position":4,"parent_id":18,"color":14867664,"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/publishing/calendars"}}} ) 

df[['Category','Subcategory']]=df['slug'].str.split('/',expand=True)
```

Comment: Getting ValueError: Columns must be same length as key, can you help? :)
```python
-> 3113             self._setitem_array(key, value)
   3114         else:
   3115             # set column

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _setitem_array(self, key, value)
   3133             if isinstance(value, DataFrame):
   3134                 if len(value.columns) != len(key):
-> 3135                     raise ValueError('Columns must be same length as key')
   3136                 for k1, k2 in zip(key, value.columns):
   3137                     self[k1] = value[k2]
```

Comment: Sorry if the comment doesn't make sense, not super familiar with the way we do it on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Hi, it's ok.  Did you call DataFrame constructor to create a dataframe?  I'm going to update the answer now

Comment: Hi, it works completely fine when I make a new dataframe from the content of one columns, but if I want to read the whole column 'category' as df and run it I get key error slug. Please check my editted post :)

Comment: Try this: frame[['category','subcategory']]=df.str.split('/',expand=True) instead of 
              frame[['category','subcategory']]=df['slug'].str.split('/',expand=True)