# Splitting a Dataframe of a Dict. to a new DataFrame with keys and values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, eval

I have a dataframe of strings. The current dataframe looks like this: 
[Current dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdtef.jpg)

Each datapoint contains a Dictionary like below:

```
"{'Index': 1, 'TimeSpent': 74088, 'RealInc': 'Obstacle_bef', 'IdentifiedIncident': 'Obstacle', 'TrLev': 7, 'TakeOverDecision': 'stay_put'},{'Index': 2, 'TimeSpent': 11336, 'RealInc': 'Obstacle_after_success', 'IdentifiedIncident': 'Pedestrian', 'TrLev': 7 },{'Index': 3, 'TimeSpent': 38594, 'RealInc': 'Cyclist_before', 'IdentifiedIncident': 'Cyclist', 'TrLev': 7, 'TakeOverDecision': 'stay_put'},{'Index': 4, 'TimeSpent': 16011, 'RealInc': 'Cyclist_after_success', 'IdentifiedIncident': 'Pedestrian', 'TrLev': 7 }".
```

I would like to make a new dataframe where each colomn represents the key of that dictionary. I have tried to use `eval()`, as well as using `apply` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/splitting-dictionary-list-inside-a-pandas-column-into-separate-columns). But I think because every other dict is missing the key of `'TakeOverDecision'`,  the apply does not work on it.

Any suggestions or guidance on how to split this to a dataset which make my dataset looks like below would be great!
[Desired dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io5sF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
   col_1 col_2
0      3     a
1      2     b
2      1     c
3      0     d
```

Comment: Thanks @AMal, from_dict works for one single dict object but in my case I have a tuple (it is the output of the eval function) with a dict as an element. do you have any solutions that I could convert the tuple to the dict and convert to the dataframe?

Comment: How about running a loop for all the elements? Performing the same operation on the entire tuple `for val in values`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `from_dict` function

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: if you mean "pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)", yes I did, it basically returns what I currently have!