# How do I extract the date from a column in a csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the 'aired' column in the csv file:
[as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXBmK.png)

Link to the csv file:
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w7kIJ5O6XIStiimowC5TLsOCUEJxuy6x/view?usp=sharing

I want to extract the date and the month (in words) from the date following the 'from' word and store it in a separate column in another csv file. The 'from' is an obstruction since had it been just the date it would have been easily extracted as a timestamp format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting from a string and want to break out the data within it. The single quotes is a clue that this is a dict structure in string form. The Python standard libraries include the `ast` (Abstract Syntax Trees) module whose `literal_eval` method can read a string into a dict, gleaned from this SO answer: [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

You want to `apply` that to your column to get the dict, at which point you expand it into separate columns using `.apply(pd.Series)`, based on this SO answer: [Splitting dictionary/list inside a Pandas Column into Separate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/splitting-dictionary-list-inside-a-pandas-column-into-separate-columns)

Try the following

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.read_csv('AnimeList.csv')
# turn the pd.Series of strings into a pd.Series of dicts
aired_dict = df['aired'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
# turn the pd.Series of dicts into a pd.Series of pd.Series objects
aired_df = aired_dict.apply(pd.Series)
# pandas automatically translates that into a pd.DataFrame
# concatenate the remainder of the dataframe with the new data
df_aired = pd.concat([df.drop(['aired'], axis=1), aired_df], axis=1)
# convert the date strings to datetime values
df_aired['aired_from'] = pd.to_datetime(df_aired['from'])
df_aired['aired_to'] = pd.to_datetime(df_aired['to'])
```

Comment: If you can share some actual data, instead of just a screenshot of the top of one column, perhaps someone can help more. I had to make some assumptions because of the lack of sufficient information in your post.

Comment: Added a link to the csv file

Comment: Edited based on additional information from OP (i.e. that it's in string form - your screenshot makes it look like it might have been a dict already).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
result = []

for cell in file['aired']:
    date = cell[8:22]
    date_ts = pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
    result.append((date_ts.month_name(), date_ts))

df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['month', 'date'])
df.to_csv('result_file.csv')
```

Comment: I get the following error:

time data '2012-01-13' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)