# How can I convert string in a column to different columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like the one shown below:

[image]

I want the output to be displayed in the following format in a dataframe:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so for? What didn't work?

Comment: See if this answer the question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38231651/454773