# How to json_normalize a column with NaNs

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, json-normalize

- This question is specific to columns of data in a `pandas.DataFrame`
- This question depends on if the values in the columns are `str`, `dict`, or `list` type.
- This question addresses dealing with the `NaN` values, when `df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)` isn't a valid option.

### Case 1

- With a column of `str` type, the values in the column must be converted to `dict` type, with `ast.literal_eval`, before using `.json_normalize`.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_str': ['{"a": "46", "b": "3", "c": "12"}', '{"b": "2", "c": "7"}', '{"c": "11"}', np.NaN]})

                            col_str
0  {"a": "46", "b": "3", "c": "12"}
1              {"b": "2", "c": "7"}
2                       {"c": "11"}
3                               NaN

type(df.iloc[0, 0])
[out]: str

df.col_str.apply(literal_eval)
```

Error:

```py
df.col_str.apply(literal_eval) results in ValueError: malformed node or string: nan
```

### Case 2

- With a column of `dict` type, use `pandas.json_normalize` to convert keys to column headers and values to rows

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_dict': [{"a": "46", "b": "3", "c": "12"}, {"b": "2", "c": "7"}, {"c": "11"}, np.NaN]})

                           col_dict
0  {'a': '46', 'b': '3', 'c': '12'}
1              {'b': '2', 'c': '7'}
2                       {'c': '11'}
3                               NaN

type(df.iloc[0, 0])
[out]: dict

pd.json_normalize(df.col_dict)
```

Error:

```py
pd.json_normalize(df.col_dict) results in AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'
```

### Case 3

- In a column of `str` type, with the `dict` inside a `list`.
- To normalize the column

  - apply `literal_eval`, because explode doesn't work on `str` type
  - explode the column to separate the `dicts` to separate rows
  - normalize the column

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_str': ['[{"a": "46", "b": "3", "c": "12"}, {"b": "2", "c": "7"}]', '[{"b": "2", "c": "7"}, {"c": "11"}]', np.nan]})

                                                    col_str
0  [{"a": "46", "b": "3", "c": "12"}, {"b": "2", "c": "7"}]
1                       [{"b": "2", "c": "7"}, {"c": "11"}]
2                                                       NaN

type(df.iloc[0, 0])
[out]: str
    
df.col_str.apply(literal_eval)
```

Error:

```py
df.col_str.apply(literal_eval) results in ValueError: malformed node or string: nan
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- There is always the option to:

  - `df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)`
  - That's fine for the dummy data here, or when dealing with a dataframe where the other columns don't matter.
  - Not a great option for dataframes with additional columns that are required.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.3`**

### Case 1

- Since the column contains `str` types, fillna with `'{}'` (a `str`)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_str': ['{"a": "46", "b": "3", "c": "12"}', '{"b": "2", "c": "7"}', '{"c": "11"}', np.NaN]})

                            col_str
0  {"a": "46", "b": "3", "c": "12"}
1              {"b": "2", "c": "7"}
2                       {"c": "11"}
3                               NaN

type(df.iloc[0, 0])
[out]: str

# fillna
df.col_str = df.col_str.fillna('{}')

# convert the column to dicts
df.col_str = df.col_str.apply(literal_eval)

# use json_normalize
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('col_str')))

# display(df)
     a    b    c
0   46    3   12
1  NaN    2    7
2  NaN  NaN   11
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

### Case 2

As of at least `pandas 1.3.4`, `pd.json_normalize(df.col_dict)` works without issue, at least for this simple example.

---

- Since the column contains `dict` types, fillna with `{}` (not a `str`)
- This needs to be filled using a dict-comprehension, since `fillna({})` does not work

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_dict': [{"a": "46", "b": "3", "c": "12"}, {"b": "2", "c": "7"}, {"c": "11"}, np.NaN]})

                           col_dict
0  {'a': '46', 'b': '3', 'c': '12'}
1              {'b': '2', 'c': '7'}
2                       {'c': '11'}
3                               NaN

type(df.iloc[0, 0])
[out]: dict
    
# fillna
df.col_dict = df.col_dict.fillna({i: {} for i in df.index})

# use json_normalize
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('col_dict')))

# display(df)
     a    b    c
0   46    3   12
1  NaN    2    7
2  NaN  NaN   11
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

### Case 3

1. Fill the `NaNs` with `'[]'` (a `str`)
2. Now `literal_eval` will work
3. `.explode` can be used on the column to separate the `dict` values to rows
4. Now the `NaNs` need to be filled with `{}` (not a `str`)
5. Then the column can be normalized

- For the case when the column is `lists` of `dicts`, that aren't `str` type, skip to `.explode`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_str': ['[{"a": "46", "b": "3", "c": "12"}, {"b": "2", "c": "7"}]', '[{"b": "2", "c": "7"}, {"c": "11"}]', np.nan]})

                                                    col_str
0  [{"a": "46", "b": "3", "c": "12"}, {"b": "2", "c": "7"}]
1                       [{"b": "2", "c": "7"}, {"c": "11"}]
2                                                       NaN

type(df.iloc[0, 0])
[out]: str
    
# fillna
df.col_str = df.col_str.fillna('[]')

# literal_eval
df.col_str = df.col_str.apply(literal_eval)

# explode
df = df.explode('col_str', ignore_index=True)

# fillna again
df.col_str = df.col_str.fillna({i: {} for i in df.index})

# use json_normalize
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('col_str')))

# display(df)
     a    b    c
0   46    3   12
1  NaN    2    7
2  NaN    2    7
3  NaN  NaN   11
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
```