# How to read AWS CloudTrail JSON Logs into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, amazon-cloudtrail, json-normalize

I have a problem as I am loading my data to pandas using Jupyterlab running with Anaconda3 as my VM suddenly went down. After it was up, I found that my code doesn't work anymore for some reason. Here is my code:

```
awsc = pd.DataFrame()
json_pattern = os.path.join('logs_old/AWSCloudtrailLog/','*')
file_list = glob.glob(json_pattern)
for file in file_list:
    data = pd.read_json(file, lines=True)
    awsc = awsc.append(data, ignore_index = True)
awsc = pd.concat([awsc, pd.json_normalize(awsc['userIdentity'])], axis=1).drop('userIdentity', 1)
awsc.rename(columns={'type':'userIdentity_type',
                     'principalId':'userIdentity_principalId',
                     'arn':'userIdentity_arn',
                     'accountId':'userIdentity_accountId',
                     'accessKeyId':'userIdentity_accessKeyId',
                     'userName':'userIdentity_userName',}, inplace=True)
```

When I run the code it gave me the KeyError message like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2888             try:
-> 2889                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2890             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'userIdentity'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-efd1d2e600a5> in <module>
      1 # unpack nested json
      2 
----> 3 awsc = pd.concat([awsc, pd.json_normalize(awsc['userIdentity'])], axis=1).drop('userIdentity', 1)
      4 awsc.rename(columns={'type':'userIdentity_type',
      5                      'principalId':'userIdentity_principalId',

~/anaconda3/envs/environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2900             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2901                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2902             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2903             if is_integer(indexer):
   2904                 indexer = [indexer]

~/anaconda3/envs/environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2889                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2890             except KeyError as err:
-> 2891                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2892 
   2893         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'userIdentity'
```

The output of the dataframe awsc as i run  print(awss.info()) or print(awsc.info()):

```
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 0 entries
Empty DataFrameNone
```

Any solution to solve this issue? Does the problem come from the Pandas or Anaconda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using Code from OP

- The method for creating the dataframe is not correct, which is way `awsc` is empty.
- Without seeing a file, it's not possible to know if `pd.read_json(file, lines=True)` is the correct method to use.
- `pd.json_normalize(awsc['userIdentity'])` will work on a column of `dicts`. It's more than likely the column is strings though.

  - If the `dicts` are `str` type, use `ast.literal_eval` to convert them to `dict` type.

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

# crate a list to add dataframes to
awsc_list = list()

# iterate through the list of and append them to awsc_list
for file in file_list:
    awsc_list.append(pd.read_json(file, lines=True))
    
# concat the files into a single dataframe
awsc = pd.concat(awsc_list).reset_index(drop=True)

# convert the userIdentity column to dict type, if it contains str type
awsc.userIdentity = awsc.userIdentity.apply(literal_eval)

# normalize userIdentity
normalized = pd.json_normalize(awsc['userIdentity'], sep='_')

# join awsc with normalized and drop the userIdentity column
awsc = awsc.join(normalized).drop('userIdentity', 1)

# rename the columns
awsc.rename(columns={'type':'userIdentity_type',
                     'principalId':'userIdentity_principalId',
                     'arn':'userIdentity_arn',
                     'accountId':'userIdentity_accountId',
                     'accessKeyId':'userIdentity_accessKeyId',
                     'userName':'userIdentity_userName',}, inplace=True)
```

### New Code with Sample Data

- The keys already have the correct name, so there is no renaming
- Using `.json_normalize` to read the logs, normalizes `'userIdentity'`, so a second step is not required.
- Also see [Splitting dictionary/list inside a Pandas Column into Separate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591)

```
import json
import pandas as pd

# crate a list to add dataframes to
awsc_list = list()

# list of files
files_list = ['test.json', 'test2.json']

# read the filess
for file in files_list:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
    
    # normalize the file and append it to the list of dataframe
    awsc_list.append(pd.json_normalize(data, 'Records', sep='_'))
    
# concat the files into a single dataframe
awsc = pd.concat(awsc_list).reset_index(drop=True)

# display(awsc)
  eventVersion             eventTime        eventSource       eventName  awsRegion  sourceIPAddress                                                                                 userAgent userIdentity_type userIdentity_principalId                      userIdentity_arn userIdentity_accessKeyId userIdentity_accountId userIdentity_userName requestParameters_instancesSet_items                                                                                                 responseElements_instancesSet_items requestParameters_force userIdentity_sessionContext_attributes_mfaAuthenticated userIdentity_sessionContext_attributes_creationDate requestParameters_keyName responseElements_keyName                              responseElements_keyFingerprint responseElements_keyMaterial
0          1.0  2014-03-06T21:22:54Z  ec2.amazonaws.com  StartInstances  us-east-2  205.251.233.176                                                                    ec2-api-tools 1.6.12.2           IAMUser          EX_PRINCIPAL_ID  arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Alice           EXAMPLE_KEY_ID           123456789012                 Alice       [{'instanceId': 'i-ebeaf9e2'}]    [{'instanceId': 'i-ebeaf9e2', 'currentState': {'code': 0, 'name': 'pending'}, 'previousState': {'code': 80, 'name': 'stopped'}}]                     NaN                                                     NaN                                                 NaN                       NaN                      NaN                                                          NaN                          NaN
1          1.0  2014-03-06T21:01:59Z  ec2.amazonaws.com   StopInstances  us-east-2  205.251.233.176                                                                    ec2-api-tools 1.6.12.2           IAMUser          EX_PRINCIPAL_ID  arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Alice           EXAMPLE_KEY_ID           123456789012                 Alice       [{'instanceId': 'i-ebeaf9e2'}]  [{'instanceId': 'i-ebeaf9e2', 'currentState': {'code': 64, 'name': 'stopping'}, 'previousState': {'code': 16, 'name': 'running'}}]                   False                                                     NaN                                                 NaN                       NaN                      NaN                                                          NaN                          NaN
2          1.0  2014-03-06T17:10:34Z  ec2.amazonaws.com   CreateKeyPair  us-east-2     72.21.198.64  EC2ConsoleBackend, aws-sdk-java/Linux/x.xx.fleetxen Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/xx           IAMUser          EX_PRINCIPAL_ID  arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Alice           EXAMPLE_KEY_ID           123456789012                 Alice                                  NaN                                                                                                                                 NaN                     NaN                                                   false                                2014-03-06T15:15:06Z                 mykeypair                mykeypair  30:1d:46:d0:5b:ad:7e:1b:b6:70:62:8b:ff:38:b5:e9:ab:5d:b8:21       <sensitiveDataRemoved>
3          1.0  2014-03-06T21:22:54Z  ec2.amazonaws.com  StartInstances  us-east-2  205.251.233.176                                                                    ec2-api-tools 1.6.12.2           IAMUser          EX_PRINCIPAL_ID  arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Alice           EXAMPLE_KEY_ID           123456789012                 Alice       [{'instanceId': 'i-ebeaf9e2'}]    [{'instanceId': 'i-ebeaf9e2', 'currentState': {'code': 0, 'name': 'pending'}, 'previousState': {'code': 80, 'name': 'stopped'}}]                     NaN                                                     NaN                                                 NaN                       NaN                      NaN                                                          NaN                          NaN
```

### Sample Data

- Sample data from [AWS: CloudTrail Log File Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-log-file-examples.html)

#### `test.json`

- List of JSONs

```json
[{
        "Records": [{
                "eventVersion": "1.0",
                "userIdentity": {
                    "type": "IAMUser",
                    "principalId": "EX_PRINCIPAL_ID",
                    "arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Alice",
                    "accessKeyId": "EXAMPLE_KEY_ID",
                    "accountId": "123456789012",
                    "userName": "Alice"
                },
                "eventTime": "2014-03-06T21:22:54Z",
                "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
                "eventName": "StartInstances",
                "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
                "sourceIPAddress": "205.251.233.176",
                "userAgent": "ec2-api-tools 1.6.12.2",
                "requestParameters": {
                    "instancesSet": {
                        "items": [{
                                "instanceId": "i-ebeaf9e2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "responseElements": {
                    "instancesSet": {
                        "items": [{
                                "instanceId": "i-ebeaf9e2",
                                "currentState": {
                                    "code": 0,
                                    "name": "pending"
                                },
                                "previousState": {
                                    "code": 80,
                                    "name": "stopped"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "Records": [{
                "eventVersion": "1.0",
                "userIdentity": {
                    "type": "IAMUser",
                    "principalId": "EX_PRINCIPAL_ID",
                    "arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Alice",
                    "accountId": "123456789012",
                    "accessKeyId": "EXAMPLE_KEY_ID",
                    "userName": "Alice"
                },
                "eventTime": "2014-03-06T21:01:59Z",
                "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
                "eventName": "StopInstances",
                "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
                "sourceIPAddress": "205.251.233.176",
                "userAgent": "ec2-api-tools 1.6.12.2",
                "requestParameters": {
                    "instancesSet": {
                        "items": [{
                                "instanceId": "i-ebeaf9e2"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "force": false
                },
                "responseElements": {
                    "instancesSet": {
                        "items": [{
                                "instanceId": "i-ebeaf9e2",
                                "currentState": {
                                    "code": 64,
                                    "name": "stopping"
                                },
                                "previousState": {
                                    "code": 16,
                                    "name": "running"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "Records": [{
                "eventVersion": "1.0",
                "userIdentity": {
                    "type": "IAMUser",
                    "principalId": "EX_PRINCIPAL_ID",
                    "arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Alice",
                    "accountId": "123456789012",
                    "accessKeyId": "EXAMPLE_KEY_ID",
                    "userName": "Alice",
                    "sessionContext": {
                        "attributes": {
                            "mfaAuthenticated": "false",
                            "creationDate": "2014-03-06T15:15:06Z"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "eventTime": "2014-03-06T17:10:34Z",
                "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
                "eventName": "CreateKeyPair",
                "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
                "sourceIPAddress": "72.21.198.64",
                "userAgent": "EC2ConsoleBackend, aws-sdk-java/Linux/x.xx.fleetxen Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/xx",
                "requestParameters": {
                    "keyName": "mykeypair"
                },
                "responseElements": {
                    "keyName": "mykeypair",
                    "keyFingerprint": "30:1d:46:d0:5b:ad:7e:1b:b6:70:62:8b:ff:38:b5:e9:ab:5d:b8:21",
                    "keyMaterial": "\u003csensitiveDataRemoved\u003e"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

#### `test2.json`

- One JSON

```json
{
    "Records": [{
            "eventVersion": "1.0",
            "userIdentity": {
                "type": "IAMUser",
                "principalId": "EX_PRINCIPAL_ID",
                "arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Alice",
                "accessKeyId": "EXAMPLE_KEY_ID",
                "accountId": "123456789012",
                "userName": "Alice"
            },
            "eventTime": "2014-03-06T21:22:54Z",
            "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
            "eventName": "StartInstances",
            "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
            "sourceIPAddress": "205.251.233.176",
            "userAgent": "ec2-api-tools 1.6.12.2",
            "requestParameters": {
                "instancesSet": {
                    "items": [{
                            "instanceId": "i-ebeaf9e2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "responseElements": {
                "instancesSet": {
                    "items": [{
                            "instanceId": "i-ebeaf9e2",
                            "currentState": {
                                "code": 0,
                                "name": "pending"
                            },
                            "previousState": {
                                "code": 80,
                                "name": "stopped"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code! I just had the time to test it out now and it really works to solve my issue. After some more digging there were some issues with the kernel due to the vm respawn from the template that required me to reinstall anaconda, pandas, and jupyterlab back to default.