# How to convert a nested dict, to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I'm trying to convert a dataframe that has inside other dataframe like:

```
{
  'id': 3241234,
  'data': {
           'name':'carol',
           'lastname': 'netflik',
           'office': {
                       'num': 3543,
                       'department': 'trigy'
                    }
        }


}
```

I tried to use:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

But the result dataframe looks like:

```
               id                                  data
lastname  3241234                               netflik
name      3241234                                 carol
office    3241234  {'num': 3543, 'department': 'trigy'}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Loading a JSON/dict:

- Using [`.json_normalized`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to expand the `dict`.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'id': 3241234, 'data': {'name': 'carol', 'lastname': 'netflik', 'office': {'num': 3543, 'department': 'trigy'}}}

df = pd.json_normalize(data)

# display(df)
        id data.name data.lastname  data.office.num data.office.department
0  3241234     carol       netflik             3543                  trigy
```

#### If the dataframe has column of `dicts`

- Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63311361), to this [SO: Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591)

```py
# dataframe with column of dicts
df = pd.DataFrame({'col2': [1, 2, 3], 'col': [data, data, data]})

# display(df)
   col2                                                                                                                col
0     1  {'id': 3241234, 'data': {'name': 'carol', 'lastname': 'netflik', 'office': {'num': 3543, 'department': 'trigy'}}}
1     2  {'id': 3241234, 'data': {'name': 'carol', 'lastname': 'netflik', 'office': {'num': 3543, 'department': 'trigy'}}}
2     3  {'id': 3241234, 'data': {'name': 'carol', 'lastname': 'netflik', 'office': {'num': 3543, 'department': 'trigy'}}}

# normalize the column of dicts
normalized = pd.json_normalize(df['col'])

# join the normalized column to df
df = df.join(normalized).drop(columns=['col'])

# display(df)
   col2       id data.name data.lastname  data.office.num data.office.department
0     1  3241234     carol       netflik             3543                  trigy
1     2  3241234     carol       netflik             3543                  trigy
2     3  3241234     carol       netflik             3543                  trigy
```

#### If the dataframe has a column of `lists` with `dicts`

- The `dicts` need to be removed from the `lists` with `.explode`

```py
data = [{'id': 3241234, 'data': {'name': 'carol', 'lastname': 'netflik', 'office': {'num': 3543, 'department': 'trigy'}}}]

df = pd.DataFrame({'col2': [1, 2, 3], 'col': [data, data, data]})

# display(df)
   col2                                                                                                                  col
0     1  [{'id': 3241234, 'data': {'name': 'carol', 'lastname': 'netflik', 'office': {'num': 3543, 'department': 'trigy'}}}]
1     2  [{'id': 3241234, 'data': {'name': 'carol', 'lastname': 'netflik', 'office': {'num': 3543, 'department': 'trigy'}}}]
2     3  [{'id': 3241234, 'data': {'name': 'carol', 'lastname': 'netflik', 'office': {'num': 3543, 'department': 'trigy'}}}]

# explode the lists
df = df.explode('col', ignore_index=True)

# remove and normalize the column of dicts
normalized = pd.json_normalize(df.pop('col'))

# join the normalized column to df
df = df.join(normalized)
```