# Conver dict into dataframe with nested keys

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a problem. I have an `array` with a `dict` inside, and this `dict` is nested. I found `pd.json_normalize(...)` but unfortunately I have many nested `keys` e.g. `contactEditor`.

I found this question [Use json_normalize to normalize json with nested arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438540/use-json-normalize-to-normalize-json-with-nested-arrays) , [How to convert a nested dict, to a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64188284/how-to-convert-a-nested-dict-to-a-pandas-dataframe) and so on, But I am not aware how to enter all the nested `keys`, I have run the code snippet below I got `KeyError: 'contactSoldToParty'`.

So how can I convert this `list` respectively this `dict` into a `dataframe`, with all the nested `keys`.

```py
df= pd.json_normalize(my_data, all_nested_keys)
```

```py
my_data = [
{'_id': 'orders/213123',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power',
  'phone': '1234567',
  'email': 'max@power.com'},
 'contactSoldToParty': {'name': 'Max Not',
  'phone': '123456789',
  'email': 'maxnot@power.com'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 'metaData': {'dataOriginSystem': 'Goods',
  'dataOriginWasCreatedTime': '10:12:12',},
 'orderDate': '2021-02-22',
 'orderDateBuyer': '2021-02-22',
},
{'_id': 'orders/12323',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power2',
  'phone': '1234567',
  'email': 'max@power.com'},
 'contactSoldToParty': {'name': 'Max Not',
  'phone': '123456789',
  'email': 'maxnot@power.com'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 'metaData': {'dataOriginSystem': 'Goods',
  'dataOriginWasCreatedTime': '10:12:12',},
 'orderDate': '2021-02-22',
 'orderDateBuyer': '2021-02-22',
 },
]
```

```py
all_nested_keys = []
for key in collection__orders_copy_new[0]:
    if isinstance(collection__orders_copy_new[0][key], dict):
        #print(key)
        all_nested_keys.append(key)

print(all_nested_keys)
```

What I want

```py
id             contactEditor_name contactEditor_phone contactEditor_email ...
orders/213123  Max Power          ...                 ...                 ...
orders/12323   Max Power2         ...                 ...                 ...
```

Comment: Given your example... does `pd.json_normalize(my_data, sep='_')` not work? (if you don't specify keys - it defaults to all (or up to N levels deep))...

Comment: @JonClements thank you for your comment. Well, that worked. I was not not clear about that.