# ValueError: malformed node or string: 0 in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column where the values are saved as a dictionary and I used the code below to untangle   the values into two separate columns, however, I am struggling with the rows that have Null values (See error msg below):
df

```
product_id    product_ratings
2323          {"average_rating": 4.2, "number_of_ratings": 10}      
4433          {"average_rating": 4.3, "number_of_ratings": 31}
3454          {"average_rating": 4.5, "number_of_ratings": 23}
4552          {"average_rating": 4.1, "number_of_ratings": 13}
3422          None
```

desired_output_df

```
product_id   average_rating  number_of_ratings
2323         4.2             10
4433         4.3             31
3454         4.5             23
4552         4.1             13
3422         0               0
```

My code:

```
import ast
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('path')
df = df.fillna(0)

dict_df = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(i) for i in df.product_ratings.values])
df2 = df.drop('product_ratings',axis=1)
final_df = pd.concat([df2,dict_df],axis=1)
final_df
```

However I am getting the following error: **ValueError: malformed node or string: 0**

Comment: This `{average_rating: 4.2, number_of_ratings: 10}` is not a valid dictionary representation. The right one is `{"average_rating": 4.2, "number_of_ratings": 10}`

Comment: sry just changed it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting dictionary/list inside a Pandas Column into Separate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/splitting-dictionary-list-inside-a-pandas-column-into-separate-columns)

Comment: the provided solution did not work for me

Comment: It seems that you have a string that is not a dict nor a literal

Comment: yes the null values in the raw data are not a dict

Comment: Try making this change to the statement
```dict_df = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(i) if type(i) is dict else 0 for i in df.product_ratings.values])```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert to dictionary, else return dictionary with default values:

```
def try_literal_eval(e):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(e)
    except ValueError:
        return {'average_rating': 0, 'number_of_ratings': 0}


res = pd.DataFrame(df['product_ratings'].apply(try_literal_eval).tolist())
output = pd.concat((df.drop('product_ratings', 1), res), axis=1)
print(output)
```

**Output**

```
   product_id  average_rating  number_of_ratings
0        2323             4.2                 10
1        4433             4.3                 31
2        3454             4.5                 23
3        4552             4.1                 13
4        3422             0.0                  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path')


dict_df = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(i) if i !='None' or i is not None else 
                        dict()
                        for i in df.product_ratings.values]
                      ).fillna(0)

final_df = df.drop('product_ratings', axis=1).join(dict_df)
```

Output:

```
   product_id  average_rating  number_of_ratings
0        2323             4.2               10.0
1        4433             4.3               31.0
2        3454             4.5               23.0
3        4552             4.1               13.0
4        3422             0.0                0.0
```

Comment: Im getting 'malformed node or string: 0' error

Comment: Can you try again without `fillna(0)` with the updated code?