# How can I delete row containing None from pandas dict?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

My dataframe is as below

```
df
    time                 home_team     away_team           full_time_result                   both_teams_to_score        double_chance                         League
--  -------------------  ------------  ------------------  ---------------------------------  -------------------------  ------------------------------------  ----------------
 0  2021-01-08 19:45:00  Charlton      Accrington Stanley  {'1': 2370, 'X': 3400, '2': 3000}  {'yes': 1900, 'no': 1900}  {'1X': 1360, '12': 1300, '2X': 1530}  England League 1
 1  2021-01-09 12:30:00  Lincoln City  Peterborough        {'1': 2290, 'X': 3400, '2': 3100}  {'yes': 1800, 'no': 1950}  {'1X': 1360, '12': 1300, '2X': 1570}  England League 1
 2  2021-01-09 13:00:00  Gillingham    Burton Albion       {'1': 2200, 'X': 3400, '2': 3300}  {'yes': 1700, 'no': 2040}  {'1X': 1330, '12': 1300, '2X': 1610}  England League 1
 3  2021-01-09 17:30:00  Ipswich       Swindon             {'1': None, 'X': None, '2': None}  {'yes': 1750, 'no': 2000}  {'1X': 1220, '12': 1250, '2X': 1900}  England League 1
```

How can I delete row containing None? as in this example in col `full_time_result` I want to delete the row  `{'1': None, 'X': None, '2': None}`

Thanks

Comment: As an FYI, since your are already expanding your columns of dicts into separate rows, as per your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65588159/7758804). The best option is to use `df_normalized = df_normalized.dropna()` after nomralizing the columns. This will be far faster than using either of the provided solutions.

Comment: This is exactly what I did while I was waiting for your solutions but, I wanted to create a more robust code handling solution hence, I adopted the solution bu @david-erickson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `lambda x:` you are going through each row of the specified column. From there, you can perform normal python operations like `any()` and access the `values()` of each row's dictionary and check if any are equal to `None`. That will return `True`, so we want to filter out these `True` results with `~`:

```
df[~df['full_time_result'].apply(lambda x: any([True for v in x.values() if v == None]))]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a boolean mask to filter out values of `full_time_result` with `None` in `'1'` and `'2'`. Tp extract  values we can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) then use [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) to check equality i.e check if it's `(None, None)`

```
from operator import itemgetter
m = df['full_time_result'].map(itemgetter('1', '2')).map((None, None).__eq__)
df[~m]

# Alternative
# m = df['full_time_result'].map(itemgetter('1', '2')).map((None, None).__ne__)
# df[m]
```

#### Details

```
_.map(itemgetter('1', '2')).map((None, None).__eq__)
# All of this can be written using lambda in single line.

_.map(lambda x: itemgetter('1', '2')(x).__eq__((None, None)))
```

---

```
example_dict = {'1': 10, '2': 20}
itemgetter('1', '2')(example_dict)
# (10, 20)

# Since you want to identify values with `None`. We can leverage on __eq__
itemgetter('1', '2')(example_dict).__eq__((10, 20))
# True # equivalent to (10, 20) == (10, 20)
```

#### timeit results

```
# Benchmarking setup
s = pd.Series([{'1':10, '2':20}, {'1':None, '2':None}, {'1':1, '2':2}])
df = s.repeat(1_000_000).to_frame('full_time_result')
df.shape
# (3000000, 1) # 3 million rows, 1 column


# @david's
In [33]: %timeit df[~df['full_time_result'].apply(lambda x: any([True for v in x.values() if v == None]))]
1.59 s ± 82.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# @Ch3steR's
In [34]: %%timeit
    ...: m = df['full_time_result'].map(itemgetter('1', '2')).map((None, None).__eq__)
    ...: df[~m]
    ...:
    ...:
834 ms ± 16.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

≈ 2X faster than using *lambda*

Comment: when `print(df[m])` I get this row value `{'1': None, 'X': None, '2': None}` but  am unable to delete it.

Comment: `df[~m]` my bad @PyNoob