# How to split a pandas column with a list of dicts into separate columns for each key

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

I'm analyzing **Political Advertisements from Facebook**, which is a [dataset](https://fbpac-images.s3.amazonaws.com/fbpac/en-US.csv.gz) released [here](https://www.propublica.org/datastore/dataset/political-advertisements-from-facebook), by ProPublica.

Here's what I mean.
I have an entire column of targets that I want to analyze but it's formatted in a very inaccessible way for someone of my skill level.

This is from just 1 cell:
`[{"target": "NAge", "segment": "21 and older"}, {"target": "MinAge", "segment": "21"}, {"target": "Retargeting", "segment": "people who may be similar to their customers"}, {"target": "Region", "segment": "the United States"}]`

and another:
`[{"target": "NAge", "segment": "18 and older"}, {"target": "Location Type", "segment": "HOME"}, {"target": "Interest", "segment": "Hispanic culture"}, {"target": "Interest", "segment": "Republican Party (United States)"}, {"target": "Location Granularity", "segment": "country"}, {"target": "Country", "segment": "the United States"}, {"target": "MinAge", "segment": 18}]`

What I need to do is to separate every "target" item to become the column label with each of its corresponding "segment" to be a possible value within that column.

Or, is the solution to create a function to call each dictionary key within each row to count frequency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The columns are `lists` of `dicts`.

  - Each `dict` in the `list` can be moved to a separate column by using `pandas.explode()`.
  - Convert the column of `dicts` to a dataframe where the keys are column headers and the values are observations, by using `pandas.json_normalize()`, `.join()` this back to `df`.
- Use `.drop()` to remove the unneeded column.
- If the column contains list of dicts that are strings (e.g. `"[{key: value}]"`), refer to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63311361/7758804) in [Splitting dictionary/list inside a Pandas Column into Separate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38231591/7758804), and use:

  - `df.col2 = df.col2.apply(literal_eval)`, with `from ast import literal_eval`.

```py
import pandas as pd

# create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['x', 'y'], 'col2': [[{"target": "NAge", "segment": "21 and older"}, {"target": "MinAge", "segment": "21"}, {"target": "Retargeting", "segment": "people who may be similar to their customers"}, {"target": "Region", "segment": "the United States"}], [{"target": "NAge", "segment": "18 and older"}, {"target": "Location Type", "segment": "HOME"}, {"target": "Interest", "segment": "Hispanic culture"}, {"target": "Interest", "segment": "Republican Party (United States)"}, {"target": "Location Granularity", "segment": "country"}, {"target": "Country", "segment": "the United States"}, {"target": "MinAge", "segment": 18}]]})

# display(df)
  col1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 col2
0    x                                                                                                                                                   [{'target': 'NAge', 'segment': '21 and older'}, {'target': 'MinAge', 'segment': '21'}, {'target': 'Retargeting', 'segment': 'people who may be similar to their customers'}, {'target': 'Region', 'segment': 'the United States'}]
1    y  [{'target': 'NAge', 'segment': '18 and older'}, {'target': 'Location Type', 'segment': 'HOME'}, {'target': 'Interest', 'segment': 'Hispanic culture'}, {'target': 'Interest', 'segment': 'Republican Party (United States)'}, {'target': 'Location Granularity', 'segment': 'country'}, {'target': 'Country', 'segment': 'the United States'}, {'target': 'MinAge', 'segment': 18}]

# use explode to give each dict in a list a separate row
df = df.explode('col2', ignore_index=True)

# normalize the column of dicts, join back to the remaining dataframe columns, and drop the unneeded column
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.col2)).drop(columns=['col2'])
```

#### `display(df)`

```
   col1                target                                       segment
0     x                  NAge                                  21 and older
1     x                MinAge                                            21
2     x           Retargeting  people who may be similar to their customers
3     x                Region                             the United States
4     y                  NAge                                  18 and older
5     y         Location Type                                          HOME
6     y              Interest                              Hispanic culture
7     y              Interest              Republican Party (United States)
8     y  Location Granularity                                       country
9     y               Country                             the United States
10    y                MinAge                                            18
```

### Get `count`

- If the goal is to get the `count` for each `'target'` and associated `'segment'`

```py
counts = df.groupby(['target', 'segment']).count()
```

### Updated

- This update is implemented for the full file

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

# load the file
df = pd.read_csv('en-US.csv')

# replace NaNs with '[]', otherwise literal_eval will error
df.targets = df.targets.fillna('[]')

# replace null with None, otherwise literal_eval will error
df.targets = df.targets.str.replace('null', 'None')

# convert the strings to lists of dicts
df.targets = df.targets.apply(literal_eval)

# use explode to give each dict in a list a separate row
df = df.explode('targets', ignore_index=True)

# fillna with {} is required for json_normalize
df.targets = df.targets.fillna({i: {} for i in df.index})

# normalize the column of dicts, join back to the remaining dataframe columns, and drop the unneeded column
normalized = pd.json_normalize(df.targets)

# get the counts
counts = normalized.groupby(['target', 'segment']).segment.count().reset_index(name='counts')
```