# How to take a column of lists of dictionary values and create new columns using their values (not keys)

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

I'm analyzing **Political Advertisements from Facebook**, which is a [dataset](https://fbpac-images.s3.amazonaws.com/fbpac/en-US.csv.gz) released [here](https://www.propublica.org/datastore/dataset/political-advertisements-from-facebook), by ProPublica.

There's an entire column of `'targets'` that I want to analyze, but it's formatted such that every observation is a `list` of `dicts` in `string` form (e.g. `"[{k1: v1}, {k2: v2}]"`).

```
import pandas as pd

data = {0: '[{"target": "Age", "segment": "18 and older"}, {"target": "MinAge", "segment": "18"}, {"target": "Segment", "segment": "Multicultural affinity: African American (US)."}, {"target": "Region", "segment": "the United States"}]', 1: '[{"target": "Age", "segment": "45 and older"}, {"target": "MinAge", "segment": "45"}, {"target": "Retargeting", "segment": "people who may be similar to their customers"}, {"target": "Region", "segment": "the United States"}]', 2: '[{"target": "Age", "segment": "18 and older"}, {"target": "MinAge", "segment": "18"}, {"target": "Region", "segment": "Texas"}, {"target": "List"}]', 3: '[]', 4: '[{"target": "Interest", "segment": "The Washington Post"}, {"target": "Gender", "segment": "men"}, {"target": "Age", "segment": "34 to 49"}, {"target": "MinAge", "segment": "34"}, {"target": "MaxAge", "segment": "49"}, {"target": "Region", "segment": "the United States"}]'}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=['targets'])

# display(df)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            targets
0                                                   [{"target": "Age", "segment": "18 and older"}, {"target": "MinAge", "segment": "18"}, {"target": "Segment", "segment": "Multicultural affinity: African American (US)."}, {"target": "Region", "segment": "the United States"}]
1                                                 [{"target": "Age", "segment": "45 and older"}, {"target": "MinAge", "segment": "45"}, {"target": "Retargeting", "segment": "people who may be similar to their customers"}, {"target": "Region", "segment": "the United States"}]
2                                                                                                                               [{"target": "Age", "segment": "18 and older"}, {"target": "MinAge", "segment": "18"}, {"target": "Region", "segment": "Texas"}, {"target": "List"}]
3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                []
4  [{"target": "Interest", "segment": "The Washington Post"}, {"target": "Gender", "segment": "men"}, {"target": "Age", "segment": "34 to 49"}, {"target": "MinAge", "segment": "34"}, {"target": "MaxAge", "segment": "49"}, {"target": "Region", "segment": "the United States"}]
```

I need to separate every `"target"` `value` to become the column header, with each corresponding `"segment"` `value` to be a value within that column.

Or, is the solution to create a function, to call each dictionary key within each row, to count frequency?

This is what it's supposed to look like as the output:

````
           NAge MinAge                                   Retargeting             Region  ...                          Interest Location Granularity            Country Gender           NAge MinAge                                   Retargeting             Region  ...                          Interest Location Granularity            Country Gender
0  21 and older     21  people who may be similar to their customers  the United States  ...                               NaN                  NaN                NaN    NaN
1  18 and older     18                                           NaN                NaN  ...  Republican Party (United States)              country  the United States    NaN
2  18 and older     18                                           NaN                NaN  ...                               NaN              country  the United States  women```
````

Someone on Reddit posted this solution:

```py
import json

for id,row in enumerate(df.targets):
    for d in json.loads(row):
        df.loc[id,d['target']] = d['segment']

df = df.drop(columns=['targets'])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-339ae1670258> in <module>
      2 for id,row in enumerate(df.targets):
      3     for d in json.loads(row):
----> 4         df.loc[id,d['target']] = d['segment']
      5 
      6 df = df.drop(columns=['targets'])

KeyError: 'segment'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `def fix()` is not vectorized, even so, it only takes 591 ms to apply to the 222186 rows in the file.
- Replace `NaN` in the column, using `.fillna()`, otherwise `literal_eval` will result in `ValueError: malformed node or string: nan`
- Replace `'null'` with `'None'`, otherwise `literal_eval` will result in `ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x000002219927A0A0>`
- The values in the `'targets'` rows are all `str` type, which can be converted to `lists` with `ast.literal_eval`.
- `def fix()` iterates through the `dicts` in the `list` and then uses only the `values` to create a `key-value` pair in a `dict`, thereby converting each `list` of `dicts` to a single `dict`.

  - Empty `lists` are replaced with empty `dicts`, which is required for `.json_normalize()` to work on the column.
- `pandas.json_normalized()` can then easily be used on the column.
- Also see [How to split a pandas column with a list of dicts into separate columns for each key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65621510/7758804) for an alternate approach with the same data.

  - As shown in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621721/7758804), it's actually easier to get all the unique counts when the `'targets'` column is expanded long wise (tidy format), using `.groupby` and aggregating `.count()`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

# load the file
df = pd.read_csv('en-US.csv')

# replace NaNs with '[]', otherwise literal_eval will error
df.targets = df.targets.fillna('[]')

# replace null with None, otherwise literal_eval will error
df.targets = df.targets.str.replace('null', 'None')

# convert the strings to lists of dicts
df.targets = df.targets.apply(literal_eval)

# function to transform the list of dicts in each row
def fix(col):
    dd = dict()
    for d in col:
        values = list(d.values())
        if len(values) == 2:
            dd[values[0]] = values[1]
    return dd

# apply the function to targets
df.targets = df.targets.apply(fix)

# display(df.targets.head())
                                                                                                                                  targets
0     {'Age': '18 and older', 'MinAge': '18', 'Segment': 'Multicultural affinity: African American (US).', 'Region': 'the United States'}
1   {'Age': '45 and older', 'MinAge': '45', 'Retargeting': 'people who may be similar to their customers', 'Region': 'the United States'}
2                                                                              {'Age': '18 and older', 'MinAge': '18', 'Region': 'Texas'}
3                                                                                                                                      {}
4  {'Interest': 'The Washington Post', 'Gender': 'men', 'Age': '34 to 49', 'MinAge': '34', 'MaxAge': '49', 'Region': 'the United States'}

# normalize the targets column
normalized = pd.json_normalize(df.targets)

# join normalized back to df if desired
df = df.join(normalized).drop(columns=['targets'])
```

### `normalized` wide-format, for the sample data

```py
# display(normalized.head())
            Age MinAge                                         Segment             Region                                   Retargeting             Interest Gender MaxAge
0  18 and older     18  Multicultural affinity: African American (US).  the United States                                           NaN                  NaN    NaN    NaN
1  45 and older     45                                             NaN  the United States  people who may be similar to their customers                  NaN    NaN    NaN
2  18 and older     18                                             NaN              Texas                                           NaN                  NaN    NaN    NaN
3           NaN    NaN                                             NaN                NaN                                           NaN                  NaN    NaN    NaN
4      34 to 49     34                                             NaN  the United States                                           NaN  The Washington Post    men     49
```

### `normalized` wide-format, for the full dataset

- As you can see from `.info()` the `targets` column contains a number of different `keys`, but not all rows contain all `keys`, so there are many `NaNs`
- In order to get the unique value counts for this wide data format, use something like `normalized.Age.value_counts()`.

```py
print(normalized.info())
[out]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 222186 entries, 0 to 222185
Data columns (total 26 columns):
 #   Column                           Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------                           --------------   ----- 
 0   Age                              157816 non-null  object
 1   MinAge                           156531 non-null  object
 2   Segment                          12288 non-null   object
 3   Region                           111638 non-null  object
 4   Retargeting                      39286 non-null   object
 5   Interest                         31514 non-null   object
 6   Gender                           7194 non-null    object
 7   MaxAge                           7767 non-null    object
 8   City                             23685 non-null   object
 9   State                            23685 non-null   object
 10  Website                          6235 non-null    object
 11  Language                         2584 non-null    object
 12  Audience Owner                   17859 non-null   object
 13  Location Granularity             29770 non-null   object
 14  Location Type                    29770 non-null   object
 15  Agency                           400 non-null     object
 16  List                             5034 non-null    object
 17  Custom Audience Match Key        1144 non-null    object
 18  Mobile App                       50 non-null      object
 19  Country                          22118 non-null   object
 20  Activity on the Facebook Family  3382 non-null    object
 21  Like                             855 non-null     object
 22  Education                        151 non-null     object
 23  Job Title                        15 non-null      object
 24  Relationship Status              22 non-null      object
 25  Employer                         4 non-null       object
dtypes: object(26)
memory usage: 44.1+ MB
```

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts to salvage this question. You have poured all this work into a question that is likely not going to help anyone besides OP due to how specific it is.

Comment: @cs95 **Thanks.** I know, right! However, these are the types of `pandas` questions I like answering. I guess, more data exploratory. I know this is a public data set, so I should update the question to include some additional key words associated with the dataset, then maybe it will come up for other people.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney This is amazing! It works! Thank you so much. I'll send you an update as I move along, but I am extremely grateful for all of your help. This dataset is so interesting and I am so happy to be digging into it and finding its patterns :D.