# json_normalize produces a KeyError when trying to extract certain attributes

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, json-normalize

Here is a subset of my json file:

```
d = {'data': {'questions': [{'id': 6574,
                             'text': 'Question #1',
                             'instructionalText': '',
                             'minimumResponses': 0,
                             'maximumResponses': None,
                             'sortOrder': 1,
                             'answers': [{'id': 362949, 'text': 'Answer #1', 'parentId': None},
                                         {'id': 362950, 'text': 'Answer #2', 'parentId': None},
                                         {'id': 362951, 'text': 'Answer #3', 'parentId': None},
                                         {'id': 362952, 'text': 'Answer #4', 'parentId': None}]}]}}
```

I want to place this into a dataframe with each question and a row for each answer.

Python code:

```
from pandas import json_normalize
import json

fields = ['text','answers.text']

with open(R'response.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

data = json_normalize(d['data'],['questions'],errors='ignore')
data = data[fields]

print(data)
```

Which produces a KeyError:

```
KeyError: "['answers.text'] not in index"
```

Been at this for a few hours and absolutely cannot figure this out. I feel like it should be quite simple, but it never is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `record_prefix`, with `record_path` and `meta`, so `d` can be normalized all at once

  - [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) will result in a `ValueError` when there are overlapping `key` names between the `record_path` and `meta`, and `'id'` and `'text'` are in both.
  - `ValueError: Conflicting metadata name id, need distinguishing prefix` occurs without using `record_path`.
- The `KeyError` occurs because `'answers.text'` is not in `d`, it's created by `.json_normalize()`
- If there are any top level `keys` that aren't required in `df`, remove them from `meta`.

```py
import pandas as pd

# normalize d
df = pd.json_normalize(data=d['data']['questions'],
                       record_path= ['answers'],
                       meta=['id', 'text', 'instructionalText', 'minimumResponses', 'maximumResponses', 'sortOrder'],
                       record_prefix='answers_')

# display(df)
   answers_id answers_text answers_parentId    id         text     instructionalText minimumResponses maximumResponses sortOrder
0      362949    Answer #1             None  6574  Question #1                                      0             None         1
1      362950    Answer #2             None  6574  Question #1                                      0             None         1
2      362951    Answer #3             None  6574  Question #1                                      0             None         1
3      362952    Answer #4             None  6574  Question #1                                      0             None         1
4      262949    Answer #1             None  4756  Question #2  No cheating, cheater                0             None         1
5      262950    Answer #2             None  4756  Question #2  No cheating, cheater                0             None         1
6      262951    Answer #3             None  4756  Question #2  No cheating, cheater                0             None         1
7      262952    Answer #4             None  4756  Question #2  No cheating, cheater                0             None         1
```

### Expanded Test Data

```py
d = {'data': {'questions': [{'id': 6574,
                             'text': 'Question #1',
                             'instructionalText': '',
                             'minimumResponses': 0,
                             'maximumResponses': None,
                             'sortOrder': 1,
                             'answers': [{'id': 362949, 'text': 'Answer #1', 'parentId': None},
                                         {'id': 362950, 'text': 'Answer #2', 'parentId': None},
                                         {'id': 362951, 'text': 'Answer #3', 'parentId': None},
                                         {'id': 362952, 'text': 'Answer #4', 'parentId': None}]},
                            {'id': 4756,
                             'text': 'Question #2',
                             'instructionalText': 'No cheating, cheater',
                             'minimumResponses': 0,
                             'maximumResponses': None,
                             'sortOrder': 1,
                             'answers': [{'id': 262949, 'text': 'Answer #1', 'parentId': None},
                                         {'id': 262950, 'text': 'Answer #2', 'parentId': None},
                                         {'id': 262951, 'text': 'Answer #3', 'parentId': None},
                                         {'id': 262952, 'text': 'Answer #4', 'parentId': None}]}]}}
```

---

- In regards to the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66070250/7758804), using `.apply(pd.Series)` is not recommended, because it is incredibly slow.

  - See the [timing analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64563986/7758804) in [SO: Splitting dictionary/list inside a Pandas Column into Separate Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38231591/7758804)
  - 53 minutes for 10M rows

Answer (score 0):

This is the technique I generally use

1. `json_normalize()` top level list
2. `explode()` child `list`, `reset_index()` for step #3
3. expand `dict` within child `list` with `apply(pd.Series)`

```
d = {'data': {'questions': [{'id': 6574,
    'text': 'Question #1',
    'instructionalText': '',
    'minimumResponses': 0,
    'maximumResponses': None,
    'sortOrder': 1,
    'answers': [{'id': 362949, 'text': 'Answer #1', 'parentId': None},
     {'id': 362950, 'text': 'Answer #2', 'parentId': None},
     {'id': 362951, 'text': 'Answer #3', 'parentId': None},
     {'id': 362952, 'text': 'Answer #4', 'parentId': None}]}]}}

df = pd.json_normalize(d["data"]["questions"]).explode("answers").reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(df["answers"].apply(pd.Series), rsuffix="_ans").drop(columns="answers")
```

|  | id | text | instructionalText | minimumResponses | maximumResponses | sortOrder | id_ans | text_ans | parentId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 6574 | Question #1 |  | 0 |  | 1 | 362949 | Answer #1 |  |
| 1 | 6574 | Question #1 |  | 0 |  | 1 | 362950 | Answer #2 |  |
| 2 | 6574 | Question #1 |  | 0 |  | 1 | 362951 | Answer #3 |  |
| 3 | 6574 | Question #1 |  | 0 |  | 1 | 362952 | Answer #4 |  |