# How to extract the value from list with dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

```
for i in range(1, len(data)):
    currentItem = data[i]
  
    df.loc[i] = [data[i]['details']]
df
# Till here its working as I can extract the data.
```

But I need to extract number value only from details

When I use below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data['details'])
number_list = df['number'].tolist() #list with numbers
```

It shows an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-126-81553db4d7eb> in <module>
      4 df
      5 
----> 6 df = pd.DataFrame(data['details'])
      7 number_list = df['number'].tolist() #list with numbers

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This is how my data looks like

[image]

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63311361/7758804) of the duplicate explains how to deal with your data, which is a column of strings, that must be converted to dicts, before being normalized. Please do not post the same question again.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by calling apply on number series. Code below will create a new column.

```
df['extracted_number'] = df.details.apply(lambda x: x['number'])
```

You can also do it with regular python loop comprehension

```
number_list = [x['number'] for x in df.details]
```