# Flatten Json into Pandas

Tags: json, pandas, normalization, flatten

I try to convert a JSON file into a DataFrame with Pandas. I use pd.json_normalize with meta but I have again in my DataFrame a dictionary nested. Maybe I can't use pd.json_normalize, do you have some idea?
Maybe I must flat the data before to use Pandas.

```py
request_json_decoding =\
{'_typ': 'Index',
 'assetClass': 'EQUITY',
 'basket': {'basketDate': '2020-12-02T00:00:00.000+0100',
            'constituents': [{'asset': {'_typ': 'Asset',
                                        'allAnalytics': [{'marketCap': 2889054400}],
                                        'assetClass': 'EQUITY',
                                        'ccy': 'EUR',
                                        'exposureCtry': 'DEU',
                                        'id': {'code': '2603021'},
                                        'moreIds': [{'codScheme': 'ISIN',
                                                     'code': 'DE000A2GS5D8'},
                                                    {'codScheme': 'SEDOL',
                                                     'code': 'BFYTTC2'},
                                                    {'codScheme': 'INST_NUM',
                                                     'code': '5679589'}],
                                        'name': 'DERMAPHARM HOLDING SE',
                                        'sectors': [{'code': '551',
                                                     'type': 'HSBC'},
                                                    {'code': '4577',
                                                     'type': 'ICB'}]},
                              'exchRate': {'rate': 1.2077999235945769},
                              'factor': 1,
                              'price': 53.66,
                              'weight': 0.0008423553691237516},
                             {'asset': {'_typ': 'Asset',
                                        'allAnalytics': [{'marketCap': 396594792}],
                                        'assetClass': 'EQUITY',
                                        'ccy': 'EUR',
                                        'exposureCtry': 'DEU',
                                        'id': {'code': '1506422'},
                                        'moreIds': [{'codScheme': 'ISIN',
                                                     'code': 'DE0007193500'},
                                                    {'codScheme': 'SEDOL',
                                                     'code': '5558203'},
                                                    {'codScheme': 'INST_NUM',
                                                     'code': '1050870'}],
                                        'name': 'KOENIG & BAUER AG',
                                        'sectors': [{'code': '331',
                                                     'type': 'HSBC'},
                                                    {'code': '2757',
                                                     'type': 'ICB'}]},
                              'exchRate': {'rate': 1.2077999235945769},
                              'factor': 1,
                              'price': 24,
                              'weight': 0.000280826220184372},
                             {'asset': {'_typ': 'Asset',
                                        'allAnalytics': [{'marketCap': 963572493.252}],
                                        'assetClass': 'EQUITY',
                                        'ccy': 'GBP',
                                        'exposureCtry': 'GBR',
                                        'id': {'code': '634295'},
                                        'moreIds': [{'codScheme': 'ISIN',
                                                     'code': 'GB00B0744359'},
                                                    {'codScheme': 'SEDOL',
                                                     'code': 'B074435'},
                                                    {'codScheme': 'INST_NUM',
                                                     'code': '1388802'}],
                                        'name': 'ESSENTRA PLC',
                                        'sectors': [{'code': '211',
                                                     'type': 'HSBC'},
                                                    {'code': '2797',
                                                     'type': 'ICB'}]},
                              'exchRate': {'rate': 1.3325000766187542},
                              'factor': 1,
                              'price': 3.194,
                              'weight': 0.0008855804882485151}]},
 'ccy': 'USD',
 'id': {'code': '33', 'source': 'INDICE'},
 'indexFreq': 'NONE',
 'indexType': 'COMPOSITE',
 'name': 'MSCI EUROPE (16) SMALL CAP',
 'pricingSourceType': 'NF',
 'sourceId': {'code': '106233', 'source': 'CODESF'}}


   
df = pd.json_normalize(request_json_decoding, ['basket', ['constituents']])
```

Output :

```py
   factor   price    weight asset._typ              asset.allAnalytics asset.assetClass asset.ccy asset.exposureCtry asset.id.code                                                                                                                             asset.moreIds             asset.name                                                       asset.sectors  exchRate.rate
0       1  53.660  0.000842      Asset     [{'marketCap': 2889054400}]           EQUITY       EUR                DEU       2603021  [{'codScheme': 'ISIN', 'code': 'DE000A2GS5D8'}, {'codScheme': 'SEDOL', 'code': 'BFYTTC2'}, {'codScheme': 'INST_NUM', 'code': '5679589'}]  DERMAPHARM HOLDING SE  [{'code': '551', 'type': 'HSBC'}, {'code': '4577', 'type': 'ICB'}]         1.2078
1       1  24.000  0.000281      Asset      [{'marketCap': 396594792}]           EQUITY       EUR                DEU       1506422  [{'codScheme': 'ISIN', 'code': 'DE0007193500'}, {'codScheme': 'SEDOL', 'code': '5558203'}, {'codScheme': 'INST_NUM', 'code': '1050870'}]      KOENIG & BAUER AG  [{'code': '331', 'type': 'HSBC'}, {'code': '2757', 'type': 'ICB'}]         1.2078
2       1   3.194  0.000886      Asset  [{'marketCap': 963572493.252}]           EQUITY       GBP                GBR        634295  [{'codScheme': 'ISIN', 'code': 'GB00B0744359'}, {'codScheme': 'SEDOL', 'code': 'B074435'}, {'codScheme': 'INST_NUM', 'code': '1388802'}]           ESSENTRA PLC  [{'code': '211', 'type': 'HSBC'}, {'code': '2797', 'type': 'ICB'}]         1.3325
```

Comment: Post an example of the df after json_normalize. It might be fixed by a simple "explode" operation.

Comment: This should be a good place to start; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/split-explode-a-column-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-with-pandas
You'll probably have to throw some extra conditionals in there to handle duplicated column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach

- initial `json_normalize()`
- repeat

  - `explode()` list
  - `reset_index(drop=True)` to ensure there is a usable join index
  - `join()` `apply(pd.Series)` to expand embedded **dict** in exploded lists

```
df = (pd.json_normalize(request_json_decoding)
 .explode("basket.constituents")
 .reset_index(drop=True)
)

df = df.join(df["basket.constituents"].apply(pd.Series)).drop(columns="basket.constituents")
df = (df.join(df["exchRate"].apply(pd.Series))
 .join(df["asset"].apply(pd.Series), rsuffix="_asset").drop(columns="asset")
 .explode("moreIds")
 .reset_index(drop=True)
)
df.join(df["moreIds"].apply(pd.Series)).drop(columns="moreIds")
```

#### sample 2 rows

|  | _typ | assetClass | ccy | indexFreq | indexType | name | pricingSourceType | basket.basketDate | id.code | id.source | sourceId.code | sourceId.source | exchRate | factor | price | weight | rate | _typ_asset | allAnalytics | assetClass_asset | ccy_asset | exposureCtry | id | name_asset | sectors | codScheme | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Index | EQUITY | USD | NONE | COMPOSITE | MSCI EUROPE (16) SMALL CAP | NF | 2020-12-02T00:00:00.000+0100 | 33 | INDICE | 106233 | CODESF | {'rate': 1.2077999235945769} | 1 | 53.66 | 0.000842355 | 1.2078 | Asset | [{'marketCap': 2889054400}] | EQUITY | EUR | DEU | {'code': '2603021'} | DERMAPHARM HOLDING SE | [{'code': '551', 'type': 'HSBC'}, {'code': '4577', 'type': 'ICB'}] | ISIN | DE000A2GS5D8 |
| 1 | Index | EQUITY | USD | NONE | COMPOSITE | MSCI EUROPE (16) SMALL CAP | NF | 2020-12-02T00:00:00.000+0100 | 33 | INDICE | 106233 | CODESF | {'rate': 1.2077999235945769} | 1 | 53.66 | 0.000842355 | 1.2078 | Asset | [{'marketCap': 2889054400}] | EQUITY | EUR | DEU | {'code': '2603021'} | DERMAPHARM HOLDING SE | [{'code': '551', 'type': 'HSBC'}, {'code': '4577', 'type': 'ICB'}] | SEDOL | BFYTTC2 |

Comment: Hello, thank you ! but in fact I work with 100 000 rows in finally so this script is very slow. I write this but it's very slow too, I add my solution in my original comments

Comment: the use of `explode()` and `apply(pd.Series)` are effectively looping not vectorised so will have performance limitations.  To truly find a more performant solution really need to limit what you want out of the JSON so that paths to convert them to pandas can be optimised

Answer (score 0):

My solution, but it's very slow because I work with 100 000 rows.

```
    %%time

    df = pd.json_normalize(request_json_decoding, ['basket', ['constituents']])
    df_infoindex = pd.json_normalize(request_json_decoding).drop(['basket.constituents'], axis=1)
    df_allanalytics = df.explode('asset.allAnalytics')
    df_allanalytics = pd.json_normalize(df_allanalytics['asset.allAnalytics'])
    name_allanalytics = df_allanalytics.columns
    df['asset.allAnalytics'] = df_allanalytics
    df.rename(columns = {'asset.allAnalytics' : name_allanalytics[0]}, inplace = True)

    #Find Codification
    codification = df['asset.moreIds'].to_dict() 
    dict_codif = {}
    for i in codification:
        if isinstance(codification[i],list):
            for ii in codification[i]:
                if i not in dict_codif:
                    dict_codif[i] = ({ii['codScheme']:ii['code']})
                else:
                    dict_codif[i].update({ii['codScheme']:ii['code']})
        else:
            dict_codif[i] = np.nan
    df_codification = pd.DataFrame(dict_codif).T


    #Find Sector
    sector = df['asset.sectors'].to_dict() 
    dict_codif = {}
    for i in sector:
        if isinstance(sector[i],list):
            for ii in sector[i]:
                if i not in dict_codif:
                    dict_codif[i] = ({ii['type']:ii['code']})
                else:
                    dict_codif[i].update({ii['type']:ii['code']})
        else:
            dict_codif[i] = np.nan
    df_sector = pd.DataFrame(dict_codif).T

    df.drop(['asset.moreIds', 'asset.sectors'], axis=1, inplace = True)
    df_return = pd.concat([df, df_codification, df_sector, 
    pd.concat([df_infoindex]*df.shape[0], ignore_index=True)], axis = 1)
```