# Extract values from Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
ID|Date|Values
1234|2021-01-01|{"Reason":"Change", "New Value":"Segment 2", "Old Value":"Segment 1"}
```

I'd like to parse the values column and create a new dataframe:

```
ID|Date|Old|New
```

The order of the values is sometimes different. How can I extract these values in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/split-explode-a-column-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-with-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

```
df[["Old", "New"]] = df["Values"].apply(lambda d: (d["Old Value"], d["New Value"])) \
                                 .tolist()
df = df.drop(columns="Values")
```

Another method:

```
import operator

old = operator.itemgetter("Old Value")
new = operator.itemgetter("New Value")

df["Old"] = df["Values"].apply(old)
df["New"] = df["Values"].apply(new)
df = df.drop(columns="Values")
```

Comment: The column is an object so I get "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: How to create your sample dataframe: `pd.DataFrame(...)`? Please can you add `df.info()` and `df.head()` output to your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.DataFrame()` to extract the dictionary into columns. Take the 2 related columns from the resulting new dataframe and join it with the original dataframe using [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and drop the original `Values` column by [`.drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

```
df_new = df.drop('Values', axis=1).join(pd.DataFrame(df['Values'].tolist())[['Old Value', 'New Value']])
```

Note that making use of `pd.DataFrame()` for extracting dictionary into columns is the fastest among various ways of doing the same task.  It is considerably faster than using `.apply()` with lambda function.

Ressult:

```
print(df_new)


     ID        Date  Old Value  New Value
0  1234  2021-01-01  Segment 1  Segment 2
```

Comment: I get the following: "None of [Index(['Old Value', 'New Value'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"