# Creating columns from dictionary rows in dataframe is assigning random values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, something like:

```
|   | a | b                |
|---|---|------------------|
| 0 | a | {'d': 1, 'e': 2} |
| 1 | b | {'d': 3, 'e': 4} |
| 2 | c | NaN              |
| 3 | d | {'f': 5}         |
| 4 | d | {'e':8,'f': 5}   |
| 5 | d | {'e':9,'f': 5}   |
| 6 | d | {'f': 7}         |
```

I am using the following code from `df.join(pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['b'].mask(df.b.isna(), {}).tolist()))` [How can I create column from dictionary keys in same dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968277/how-can-i-create-column-from-dictionary-keys-in-same-dataframe) and getting result like:

```
|   | a | b                | d | e | f |
|---|---|------------------|---|---|---|
| 0 | a | {'d': 1, 'e': 2} | 1 | 2 |nan|
| 1 | b | {'d': 3, 'e': 4} | 3 | 8 |nan|
| 2 | c | NaN              |nan|nan|nan|
| 3 | d | {'f': 5}         |nan|nan| 5 |
| 4 | d | {'e':8,'f': 5}   |nan| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | d | {'e':9,'f': 5}   |nan|nan| 5 |
| 6 | d | {'f': 7}         |nan|nan| 7 |
```

Why are the values in **e** randomly getting allocated and not by there adjascent rows?
How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `b` column in the above and below do not match? Is that intentional?

Comment: @HenryEcker, I guess that's a typo

Comment: @HenryEcker not the b column, if you look at the expanded columns **e** and it's value in **b**

Comment: Right. But row 4 and 5 are `{'e':4,'f': 5}` and `{'e':2,'f': 5}` above and `{'e':8,'f': 5}` `{'e':9,'f': 5}` below. I don't know which data to start with to try and replicate the issue.

Comment: Maybe that should be the point of my question. I cannot replicate this behaviour, would you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a single contiguous block of code that can be copied into a clean workspace and reproduce the issue?

Comment: @HenryEcker sorry it was a typo, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason should be original DataFrame has no default `RangeIndex`, so after `join` is wrongly assigned new `DataFrame`, which has by default default index.

You need set index values by `df.index` for correct align new DataFrame.

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['b'].mask(df.b.isna(), {}).tolist(), index=df.index))
```