# split json within dataframe column into multiple column in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

actually I am fetching data from database
which has data as below CSV format

```
DS,SID,SID_T,E_DATE,S_DATA
TECH,312,TID,2021-01-03,"{""idx"":""msc"",""cid"":""f323d3"",""iname"":""master_in_science"",""mcap"":21.33,""sg"":[{""upt"":true,""dwt"":true,""high_low"":false}]}"
TECH,343,TID,2021-01-03,"{""idx"":""bsc"",""cid"":""k33d3"",""iname"":""bachelor_in_science"",""mcap"":81.33,""sg"":[{""upt"":false,""dwt"":true,""high_low"":false}]}"
TECH,554,TID,2021-01-03,"{""idx"":""ba"",""cid"":""3d3f32"",""iname"":""bachelor_in_art"",""mcap"":67.83,""sg"":[{""upt"":true,""dwt"":false,""high_low"":false}]}"
TECH,323,TID,2021-01-03,"{""idx"":""ma"",""cid"":""m23k66"",""iname"":""master_in_art"",""mcap"":97.13,""sg"":[{""upt"":true,""dwt"":true,""high_low"":true}]}"
```

dataframe look like this
[image]

i wanted to split the S_DATA column into multiple column
hence the output is like this
[image]

what i have tried
i tried to convert the dataframe into json + and trying to normalize the json using pandas.normalize

but i was unable to do the so

also S_DATA.sg values i.e.""sg"":[{""upt"":`true`,""dwt"":`true`,""high_low"":`false`} is also creating the trouble while the entire conversion process

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/split-explode-a-column-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-with-pandas ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['S_DATA'] = df['S_DATA'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x))
pd.concat([df[df.columns.difference(['S_DATA'])], pd.json_normalize(df.S_DATA)], axis=1)
```