# Convert dictionary keys to rows and show all the values in single column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've dataset as in following format :

```
df = pd.read_csv("data_processing.csv")
df
    user_id volume
0   a       {"BTCUSDT":1000,"USDTINR":20}
1   b       {"BTCINR":30,"USDTINR":10,"ETHINR":15}
2   c       {"XRPINR":10,"ETHUSDT":500,"XRPUSDT":200}
3   d       {"ETHINR":5}
```

I want to convert the above dataset in following format :

```
df
   user_id  symbol  volume
0   a       BTCUSDT 1000.0
1   a       USDTINR 20.0
2   b       USDTINR 10.0
3   b       BTCINR  30.0
4   b       ETHINR  15.0
5   c       XRPINR  10.0
6   c       ETHUSDT 500.0
7   c       XRPUSDT 200.0
8   d       ETHINR  5.0'
```

##### What I've tried till now :

###### Converted string to dict for "volume" column

df['volume'] = df['volume'].map(eval)

###### converted volume column to from dict to all the keys in one column and all the values in another column

df2 = pd.json_normalize(df['volume']).stack().to_frame(name='volume').reset_index()

But now I'm finding it difficult to map the user_id's to the output of above dataframe.

Comment: @jezrael This question is not a dupe. I'm reopening the question.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - Ya, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

One Way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd'},
 'volume': {0: {'BTCUSDT': 1000, 'USDTINR': 20},
  1: {'BTCINR': 30, 'USDTINR': 10, 'ETHINR': 15},
  2: {'XRPINR': 10, 'ETHUSDT': 500, 'XRPUSDT': 200},
  3: {'ETHINR': 5}}})

df = df.join(df.pop('volume').apply(pd.Series)).stack().reset_index()
```

OUTPUT:

```
 level_0  level_1  0
0       a  BTCUSDT  1000.0
1       a  USDTINR    20.0
2       b  USDTINR    10.0
3       b   BTCINR    30.0
4       b   ETHINR    15.0
5       c   XRPINR    10.0
6       c  ETHUSDT   500.0
7       c  XRPUSDT   200.0
8       d   ETHINR     5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can convert the volume dict to a list of key-value pairs like `[(BTCUSDT, 1000), (USDTINR, 20)]` for each row, then you use `explode` to put them on different rows and convert them to 2 columns. Finally join it back to the original df.

```
(
    df.drop('volume', 1)
    .join(df.volume.apply(lambda x: list(x.items())).explode().apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x, ['symbol', 'volume'])))
)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!
Can you please elaborate like how it worked?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pd.DataFrame()` to expand the dict into columns. Then, use [.`stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to convert the expanded columns into rows, as follows:

```
df_out = (df.drop('volume', axis=1).join(pd.DataFrame(df['volume'].tolist(), index=df.index))
            .set_index('user_id', append=True).stack().reset_index([1,2])
         )
df_out.columns = ['user_id', 'symbol', 'volume']
```

**Expansion by `pd.DataFrame` generally has faster execution than expansion via `pd.Series`.**  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66221984/15070697) of another post [Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38231591/15070697) for details.

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

  user_id   symbol  volume
0       a  BTCUSDT  1000.0
0       a  USDTINR    20.0
1       b  USDTINR    10.0
1       b   BTCINR    30.0
1       b   ETHINR    15.0
2       c   XRPINR    10.0
2       c  ETHUSDT   500.0
2       c  XRPUSDT   200.0
3       d   ETHINR     5.0
```