# Python - Converting Date:Price list to new rows

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, key-value

I am trying to convert the following column into new rows:

| Id | Prices |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | ["March:59", "April:64", "May:62"] |
| 002 | ["Jan:55", ETC] |

to

| id | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | March | 59 |
| 001 | April | 64 |
| 001 | May | 62 |
| 002 | Jan | 55 |

The date:price pairs aren't stored in a traditional dictionary format like the following solution:

[Convert dictionary keys to rows and show all the values in single column using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68219903/convert-dictionary-keys-to-rows-and-show-all-the-values-in-single-column-using-p)

I managed to get the key:value pairs into individual rows like:

| Id | Prices |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | March:59 |
| 001 | April:64 |

And could split these into two columns using string manipulation but this feels inefficient instead of actually using the key:value pairs. Can anyone help please?

Comment: You need to use [split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on your 'nearly there' data, because your data ***are*** lists of strings, ***not*** key value pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have valid lists, [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': ['001', '002'],
                   'Prices':   [["March:59", "April:64", "May:62"], ["Jan:55"]]})

out = df.explode('Prices')
out[['date', 'price']] = out.pop('Prices').str.split(':', expand=True)
```

If you have strings, [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with a regex and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': ['001', '002'],
                   'Prices':   ['["March:59", "April:64", "May:62"]', '["Jan:55"]']})

out = (df.drop(columns='Prices') 
          .join(df['Prices'].str.extractall(r'(?P<date>[^":]+):(?P<price>[^":]+)')
                .droplevel('match'))
       )
```

Output:

```
    Id   date price
0  001  March    59
0  001  April    64
0  001    May    62
1  002    Jan    55
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PrkODm/1) for the second approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
# apply ast.literal_eval if necessary:
from ast import literal_eval

df["Prices"] = df["Prices"].apply(literal_eval)

df = df.explode("Prices")
df[["date", "price"]] = df.pop("Prices").str.split(":", n=1, regex=False).to_list()

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Id   date price
0   1  March    59
0   1  April    64
0   1    May    62
1   2    Jan    55
```