# How do I convert this column into multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ndjson

My pandas DataFrame looks like this:

| id | address |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{'city': 'MURFREESBORO', 'line': ['9999 Candy Cane Island'], 'postalCode': '39999', 'state': '56'}] |
| 2 | [{'city': 'LIKELAND', 'line': ['11111 WS 80RD ST'], 'postalCode': '71398', 'state': '99'}] |
| 3 | [{'city': 'CHASS', 'line': ['36 LONDON LN'], 'postalCode': '269235', 'state': '35'}] |

How do I convert this column into multiple columns to look like this?

| id | city | line | postalcode | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MURFREESBORO | 9999 Candy Cane Island | 39999 | 56 |
| 2 | LIKELAND | 11111 WS 80RD ST | 71398 | 99 |
| 3 | CHASS | 36 LONDON LN | 269235 | 35 |

I have tried multiple different ways:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(newdf['address'])

# AND
newdf['address'] = newdf['address'].apply(lambda x: "'" + str(x) + "'")
newdf['address'] = newdf['address'].apply(str).str.replace('[', '').str.replace(']', '')
```

Data to construct the DataFrame:

```
{'id': [1, 2, 3],
 'address': [[{'city': 'MURFREESBORO', 'line': ['9999 Candy Cane Island'],
               'postalCode': '39999', 'state': '56'}],
             [{'city': 'LIKELAND', 'line': ['11111 WS 80RD ST'],
               'postalCode': '71398', 'state': '99'}],
             [{'city': 'CHASS','line': ['36 LONDON LN'],
               'postalCode': '269235', 'state': '35'}]]}
```

Comment: Is "line" always going to contain one value?

Comment: What is the output of `df = pd.json_normalize(newdf['address'])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/split-explode-a-column-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-with-pandas)

Answer (score 2):

You could `explode` "address" column, convert it to a list and construct a DataFrame with it; then `join` it back to `df`:

```
s = df['address'].explode()
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index).explode('line')).drop(columns='address')
```

Output:

```
   id          city                    line postalCode state
0   1  MURFREESBORO  9999 Candy Cane Island      39999    56
1   2      LIKELAND        11111 WS 80RD ST      71398    99
2   3         CHASS            36 LONDON LN     269235    35
```

Comment: Do you know what happens if, for example, if there was two of the same keys for example: {("city": "Murfreesboro", "city": "Smithville")} ?

Comment: @user17629522 that's not possible in python because keys have to be unique in a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

First change 1-element list in each element of *address* column into
the content of this element.

Then you can invoke *json_normalize* on the result of step 1 and save
the result in a temporary DataFrame.

Both above operations can be performed as:

```
wrk = pd.json_normalize(df.address.str[0])
```

There is one more conversion to perform, i.e. change 1-element list
in each element of *line* column into the content of this element:

```
wrk.line = wrk.line.str[0]
```

And the last step is to join *id* column with *wrk*:

```
result = df[['id']].join(wrk)
```

The result is:

```
   id          city                    line postalCode state
0   1  MURFREESBORO  9999 Candy Cane Island      39999    56
1   2      LIKELAND        11111 WS 80RD ST      71398    99
2   3         CHASS            36 LONDON LN     269235    35
```

The leftmost column is the index, which you didn't include in your post.

To easier comprehend how the above code works, print *wrk* after
each step of my code.