# Dictionary inside a pandas dataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas `DataFrame`, called `d`, that looks like this:

```
0      {'energies': [[0, 100, 1, 17.537183749262393, ...
1      {'energies': [[0, 100, 1, 0.5002560191707848, ...
2      {'energies': [[0, 100, 1, 0.833607984160617, 0...
3      {'energies': [[0, 100, 1, 2.0271986592908204, ...
4      {'energies': [[0, 100, 1, 0.20764045065127334,...
                             ...                        
119    {'energies': [[0, 100, 1, 0.6830323011861984, ...
120    {'energies': [[0, 100, 1, 3.9571018617595075, ...
121    {'energies': [[0, 100, 1, 4.815231137572439, 4...
122    {'energies': [[0, 100, 1, 33.556514163996766, ...
123    {'energies': [[0, 100, 1, 5.467475908262811, 5...
Name: results, Length: 124, dtype: object
```

How do I get rid of the dictionary? Have tried `d['energies']`, but get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\LinearRegresseionEENX15\LinearRegression.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(d['energies'])
  File "C:\LinearRegresseionEENX15\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "C:\LinearRegresseionEENX15\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1069, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\LinearRegresseionEENX15\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 389, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'energies'
```

I can access the individual lists by using `d[0]['energies']`. But I want to do this for the whole dataframe.

Comment: please include the dataframe constructor; i.e. `df.head().to_dict()`. Also, what's your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is similar to this one: [Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/split-explode-a-column-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-with-pandas).

Pandas has a json_normalize() function that splits the dictionary out into its own columns. Assuming your dictionary column is the first column in your dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df[0])
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks! Just used `pd.json_normalize(d[:])` to do this for the whole dataframe.