# Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I export a Postgres SQL query to create the following Pandas data frame `df`:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
    'employee_id' : [123, 456, 789],
    'sales' : [{'foo':2, 'bar': 0, 'baz': 1},
               {'foo':3, 'bar': 1, 'baz': 2},
               {'foo':7, 'bar': 0, 'baz': 4}]
})

df
 
    employee_id sales
0   123 {'foo': 2, 'bar': 0, 'baz': 1}
1   456 {'foo': 3, 'bar': 1, 'baz': 2}
2   789 {'foo': 7, 'bar': 0, 'baz': 4}
```

The data types are:

```
df.dtypes

employee_id     int64
sales          object
dtype: object
```

I would like to split the `sales` column of dictionaries into separate columns ***by the keys***, as follows:

```
    employee_id   foo    bar   baz
0   123           2      0     1
1   456           3      1     2
2   789           7      0     4
```

Following the advise in [Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/split-explode-a-column-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-with-pandas/64563986#64563986), I do so using the following:

```
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df['sales'])
```

Which gives:

```
df2.head()

0
1
2
3
4
```

When I apply this approach to non-production data, it works.

How do I split the `sales` column into 3 separate columns?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your Postgres SQL query really returns a dictionary?

Comment: It **appears** to, yes.  What is the default output?

Comment: I don't know, you can check with `type`

Comment: See above.  The type shows "object".

Comment: I mean the type of value in Series

Comment: How do I see that?

Comment: `print(type(df['sales'].iloc[0]))`

Comment: It shows:  <class 'str'>

Comment: It's not dictionary, you can try use `eval` or something to try to convert it to dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following thing:

Use the function:

```
def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    
    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    
    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            horiz_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            horiz_exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, horiz_exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(horiz_exploded.columns) # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            print(f"exploding: {col}")
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    return df
```

This function works on any nested df and explodes all columns:

```
flatten_nested_json_df(df)
```

which returns:

```
   index  employee_id  sales.foo  sales.bar  sales.baz
0      0          123          2          0          1
1      1          456          3          1          2
2      2          789          7          0          4
```