# How to create box plots from columns of dicts in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn, boxplot, json-normalize

- I have a dataframe where each row is a dictionary on which I'd like to use [seaborn's horizontal box plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/horizontal_boxplot.html).

  1. The x axis should be the float values for each `'dialog'`
  2. The y axis should show the 4 different models
  3. There should be a plot for *each parts of speech*, meaning there should be a graph for 'INTJ', another for 'ADV' and so on.
- I'm thinking I'll have to do a `pd.melt` first to restructure the data first so that the new columns would be `'dialog_num'`, `'model_type'`, and `'value'` (automatic variable name after doing a melt, but basically the rows of dictionaries).
- After that, perhaps break the `'value'` variable so that each column is a part of speech ('ADV', 'INTJ', 'VERB', etc.) *(this part seems tricky to me)*. Past this point...do a for loop on all of the columns and apply the horizontal boxplot?

```py
import pandas as pd

pos =\
{'dialog_num': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2},
 'model1': {0: {'ADV': 0.072, 'INTJ': 0.03, 'PRON': 0.133, 'VERB': 0.109},
            1: {'ADJ': 0.03, 'NOUN': 0.2, 'PRON': 0.13},
            2: {'ADV': 0.083, 'PRON': 0.125, 'VERB': 0.0625}},
 'model2': {0: {'ADJ': 0.1428, 'ADV': 0.1428, 'AUX': 0.1428, 'INTJ': 0.285},
            1: {'ADJ': 0.1, 'DET': 0.1, 'NOUN': 0.1, 'PROPN': 0.1, 'VERB': 0.2},
            2: {'CCONJ': 0.166, 'NOUN': 0.333, 'SPACE': 0.166, 'VERB': 0.3333}},
 'model3': {0: {'ADJ': 0.06, 'CCONJ': 0.06, 'NOUN': 0.2, 'PRON': 0.266, 'SPACE': 0.066, 'VERB': 0.333},
            1: {'AUX': 0.15, 'PRON': 0.25, 'PUNCT': 0.15, 'VERB': 0.15},
            2: {'ADP': 0.125, 'PRON': 0.0625, 'PUNCT': 0.0625, 'VERB': 0.25}},
 'model4': {0: {'ADJ': 0.25, 'ADV': 0.08, 'CCONJ': 0.083, 'PRON': 0.166},
            1: {'AUX': 0.33, 'PRON': 0.2, 'VERB': 0.0667},
            2: {'CCONJ': 0.125, 'NOUN': 0.125, 'PART': 0.125, 'PRON': 0.125, 'SPACE': 0.125, 'VERB': 0.375}}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pos)
```

```
display(df)
   dialog_num                                                      model1                                                            model2                                                                                   model3                                                                                        model4
0           0  {'INTJ': 0.03, 'ADV': 0.072, 'PRON': 0.133, 'VERB': 0.109}      {'INTJ': 0.285, 'AUX': 0.1428, 'ADV': 0.1428, 'ADJ': 0.1428}  {'PRON': 0.266, 'VERB': 0.333, 'ADJ': 0.06, 'NOUN': 0.2, 'CCONJ': 0.06, 'SPACE': 0.066}                                     {'PRON': 0.166, 'ADV': 0.08, 'ADJ': 0.25, 'CCONJ': 0.083}
1           1                    {'PRON': 0.13, 'ADJ': 0.03, 'NOUN': 0.2}  {'PROPN': 0.1, 'VERB': 0.2, 'DET': 0.1, 'ADJ': 0.1, 'NOUN': 0.1}                                 {'PRON': 0.25, 'AUX': 0.15, 'VERB': 0.15, 'PUNCT': 0.15}                                                    {'PRON': 0.2, 'AUX': 0.33, 'VERB': 0.0667}
2           2               {'PRON': 0.125, 'ADV': 0.083, 'VERB': 0.0625}   {'VERB': 0.3333, 'CCONJ': 0.166, 'NOUN': 0.333, 'SPACE': 0.166}                            {'PRON': 0.0625, 'VERB': 0.25, 'PUNCT': 0.0625, 'ADP': 0.125}  {'PRON': 0.125, 'VERB': 0.375, 'PART': 0.125, 'CCONJ': 0.125, 'NOUN': 0.125, 'SPACE': 0.125}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`sns.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) expects `data` to be supplied in a long form when specifying `x=` and `y=`.
- In this case, based on the specifications of having each speech type as a separate plot, [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot) will be used because there is a `col=` parameter, which can be used to create separate plots for speech types.

1. As mentioned in the OP, use [`.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to unpivot the wide dataframe.
2. [`.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) can be used to convert the the `'value'` column (`dict` type) into a flat table.

   - See [Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63311361/7758804) if there are issues with this step.
3. Join the flattened table (`vals`) to `dfm` with [`.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).

   - This works because `vals` and `dfm` have matching indices.
4. `.melt` the dataframe again.
5. Plot the box plot from the long form dataframe.

- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# load the dict into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(pos)

# unpivot the dataframe
dfm = df.melt(id_vars='dialog_num', var_name='model')

# convert the 'value' column of dicts to a flat table
vals = pd.json_normalize(dfm['value'])

# combine vals to dfm, without the 'value' column
dfm = dfm.iloc[:, 0:-1].join(vals)

# unpivot the dataframe again
dfm = dfm.melt(id_vars=['dialog_num', 'model'])
```

### plot all of the speech types together

```py
p = sns.boxplot(data=dfm, x='value', y='model')
```

[image]

### plot speech types separately

- Most speech types have only a single value, or no values.

```py
p = sns.catplot(kind='box', data=dfm, x='value', y='model', col='variable', col_wrap=4, height=4)
```

[image]

### DataFrames at each step

#### 1: `dfm.head()`

```
   dialog_num   model                                                             value
0           0  model1        {'INTJ': 0.03, 'ADV': 0.072, 'PRON': 0.133, 'VERB': 0.109}
1           1  model1                          {'PRON': 0.13, 'ADJ': 0.03, 'NOUN': 0.2}
2           2  model1                     {'PRON': 0.125, 'ADV': 0.083, 'VERB': 0.0625}
3           0  model2      {'INTJ': 0.285, 'AUX': 0.1428, 'ADV': 0.1428, 'ADJ': 0.1428}
4           1  model2  {'PROPN': 0.1, 'VERB': 0.2, 'DET': 0.1, 'ADJ': 0.1, 'NOUN': 0.1}
```

#### 2: `vals.head()`

```
    INTJ     ADV   PRON    VERB     ADJ  NOUN     AUX  PROPN  DET  CCONJ  SPACE  PUNCT  ADP  PART
0  0.030  0.0720  0.133  0.1090     NaN   NaN     NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
1    NaN     NaN  0.130     NaN  0.0300   0.2     NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
2    NaN  0.0830  0.125  0.0625     NaN   NaN     NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
3  0.285  0.1428    NaN     NaN  0.1428   NaN  0.1428    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
4    NaN     NaN    NaN  0.2000  0.1000   0.1     NaN    0.1  0.1    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
```

#### 3: `dfm.head()`

```
   dialog_num   model   INTJ     ADV   PRON    VERB     ADJ  NOUN     AUX  PROPN  DET  CCONJ  SPACE  PUNCT  ADP  PART
0           0  model1  0.030  0.0720  0.133  0.1090     NaN   NaN     NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
1           1  model1    NaN     NaN  0.130     NaN  0.0300   0.2     NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
2           2  model1    NaN  0.0830  0.125  0.0625     NaN   NaN     NaN    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
3           0  model2  0.285  0.1428    NaN     NaN  0.1428   NaN  0.1428    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
4           1  model2    NaN     NaN    NaN  0.2000  0.1000   0.1     NaN    0.1  0.1    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN
```

#### 4: `dfm.head()`

```
   dialog_num   model variable  value
0           0  model1     INTJ  0.030
1           1  model1     INTJ    NaN
2           2  model1     INTJ    NaN
3           0  model2     INTJ  0.285
4           1  model2     INTJ    NaN
```