# how to convert string column to multiple columns in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have csv file , which have one column and inside this column have string , string contains many values , i want to convert this string in muultiple columns

here is example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':[{'A':2,'B':3,'c':2}]})
print(df)
                    column1
0  {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'c': 2}
1  {'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'c': 10}
i want output:

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2],'B':[3],'c':[2]})
```

i got this solution and it's work but this solution have * expression i am not sure this is about what. except this have any other effiecient solution ?

```
pd.DataFrame([*df['column1'].apply(eval)])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/split-explode-a-column-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-with-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [{'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 2}, {'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'C': 10}]})
allkeys = set().union(*df['column1'])
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: [[d[k] for d in df['column1'] if k in d]] for k in allkeys})
```

output is

```
         C       B       A
0  [2, 10]  [3, 5]  [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your original question of "what does * expression mean", I believe this explanation would help.

**PEP 448 proposes extended usages of the * iterable unpacking operator and ** dictionary unpacking operators to allow unpacking in more positions, an arbitrary number of times, and in additional circumstances. Specifically, in function calls, in comprehensions and generator expressions, and in displays.**

The documentation

https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/