# how to extract database column in json format into multiple columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have  a database column that's been converted to a Pandas dataframe and it looks like below . My actual data has much more columns and rows with different `key: value` pair.

```
df["Records"]
{"ID":"1","ID_1":"40309","type":"type1"}
{"ID":"2","ID_1":"40310","type":"type1"}
{"ID":"3","ID_1":"40311","type":"type1"}
```

I want to split this into multiple columns in a dataframe.

```
df1:
ID  ID_1   type
1   40309  type1
2   40310  type1
3   40311  type1
```

I tried this code

```
json_Str=df.to_dict()
json_dump= json.dumps(json_Str)
json_dump=json_dump.replace("\\", "")
with open("H:\\df2.json", 'w') as fp:
    # json.dump(result, fp, indent=4)
    print(json_dump, file=fp)
```

output file has dictionary key value pair

Output:

```
{"Records":"{"ID":"1","ID_1":"40309","type":"type1"}
{"ID":"2","ID_1":"40310","type":"type1"}
{"ID":"3","ID_1":"40311","type":"type1"}"}
```

How do I convert a json column to csv format in pandas?

Comment: should `df["Records"]` be set equal (`=`) to the dictionary instead of using a colon (`:`)?

Comment: input has colon.  output doesnt matter . it should just be in different columns ..df1[0,1,2]: 1,40309,type1 this is nothing but df1[0]=1, df1[1]=40309,df1[2]=type1

Comment: can you supply a sample of data so we have something to build off of? `df["Records"]:{"ID":"1","ID_1":"40309","type":"type1"}` doesn't help much

Comment: I added few more columns .

Comment: Does my answer below not produce what you need?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/split-explode-a-column-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-with-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

not entirely sure I understand the question but if youre just trying to take your data out of index, just use

`df1.reset_index(drop=False)`

or if youre trying to convert rows to columns you could use `df1.transpose()`

Comment: i am just trying to split json column from database to multiple columns in pandas dataframe.. I edited my post to make it more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after

```
# using the same data repeatedly to highlight effect
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Records": [
        {"ID":"1","ID_1":"40309","type":"type1"},
        {"ID":"1","ID_1":"40309","type":"type1"},
        {"ID":"1","ID_1":"40309","type":"type1"}
    ]
})

# start data looks like...
print(df)

                                         Records
0  {'ID': '1', 'ID_1': '40309', 'type': 'type1'}
1  {'ID': '1', 'ID_1': '40309', 'type': 'type1'}
2  {'ID': '1', 'ID_1': '40309', 'type': 'type1'}
```

```
# "explode" the dictionaries in df.Records
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.Records.to_list())

print(df1)

  ID   ID_1   type
0  1  40309  type1
1  1  40309  type1
2  1  40309  type1
```

Reference -- [Split a Pandas column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35491274/6509519)

Comment: this throws error.. it says 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Records'

Comment: If your `df` has a column called `"Records"` it won't raise the error. In your question, please provide code to generate a sample of you data. The code you gave isn't currently in an acceptable `pandas` format. Or are you saying that error raises after running my code exclusively?

Comment: thanks Ian.. It does not solve the issue. there is no error but output is same  wth header being 0.

Comment: @unicorn please provide code that produces your data and your error

Comment: I added code and result i am getting.. does that make sense?. this is all i did.

Comment: The first code block you provided isn't runnable / I'm not sure what to do with it. What is "Output" (the json looking thing at the end of your question)? Is that actually your input? Or what you want your output to look like? Give us a copy/pastable `df` or code to create a `df` that looks like your `df` so we can move forward