# exploding a multi dictionnary columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-explode

I have a data that contains +15 columns all of them with dictionnary as values. all of the dictionnary has the same keys but different values depending on th column and the key of course. i need to explode them into on data that has the keys as index;[this a part of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dq4H.png)

i ve tried this code ! but it only work on one column. i have to do it for all 15 columns and merge them.

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[i, k, v] for i, d in df[['halstead_vol', 'cyclomatic_complexity']].values for k, v in d.items()],
                  columns=['halstead_vol', 'cyclomatic_complexity', 'h1'])
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible input and the expected output, currently the question is too vague to give a clear answer without guessing what you might want

Answer (score 0):

If you check [explode function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) documentation in pandas, to explode multiple column you can achieve that in this format:

```
DataFrame.explode(list(col1col2col3...))
```

for your case:

```
df.explode(list('halstead_volcyclomatic_complexityh1'), ignore_index=True)
```

For dictionary values try this:

```
new_df = df['halstead_vol'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/split-explode-a-column-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-with-pandas) on SO for more info.

Comment: it works only for lists! it doesn't work for dictionnary

Comment: @tahaelbermaki try dictionary code.