# How to transform a DataFrame with a complicated series in a new DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, series

I'm going through a hard time trying to transform a dataframe with 2 columns into another DataFrame. The first column is my index (ints) and the another column is a complicated series. For what i'm able to see the structure of the series goes like this:

A dictionary with one key and one value. The value is a list of simple dictionaries with key/value pairs.

My DataFrame looks like that:

[image]

Series:

```
{
"CashFlowDto": [
    {
        "TicketId": None,
        "Type": "Amrt",
        "Amount": 560.61,
        "PercentualAmount": 0.0494481,
        "MaturityDate": datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 10, 0, 0),
        "PaymentDate": datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 10, 0, 0),
    },
    {
        "TicketId": None,
        "Type": "Amrt",
        "Amount": 552.05,
        "PercentualAmount": 0.048693,
        "MaturityDate": datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 10, 0, 0),
        "PaymentDate": datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 10, 0, 0),
    }
]}
```

My desired output:

[image]

Could you guys help me, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this by applying [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to your original data, but I'll suggest a solution using [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) (and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)).

If your current DataFrame is named [`tickets_df`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkg2y.png), then you can try

```py
cashflows_df = pd.DataFrame([{'Ticket': tId, **{
    k: v for k, v in cfd.items() if k != 'TicketId'
}} for tId, cf in zip(
    # tickets_df['TicketId'], tickets_df['CashFlows']
    tickets_df.index, tickets_df['CashFlows'] # if TicketId is the index
) for cfd in cf['CashFlowDto']])
```

> [image: op]
> <sup>(I edited the `Type` field just to demonstrate that the rows are separate as they should be.)</sup>

Comment: Nice, solved my problem bro.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

- First, use [`Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) on column `CashFlowDto` and use within [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63311361/18470692).
- Next, repeat the result *n* times (i.e. `n = len(df)`) using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), and make sure to put parameter `ignore_index` to `True`.
- Now, also get a repeat for `df['TicketId']`, for which we can use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), and keep only the values (using [`Series.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.0rc1/api/generated/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html); alternatively, reset `Series.index`).
- Finally, combine the new `df` and the repeats for `df['TicketId']`, using [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html).

```
n = len(df)
res = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df['CashFlowDto'].tolist())]*n,ignore_index=True)
       .assign(TicketId=np.repeat(df.TicketId, n).to_numpy()))

res

   TicketId  Type  Amount  PercentualAmount MaturityDate PaymentDate
0         1  Amrt  560.61          0.049448   2023-07-10  2023-07-10
1         1  Amrt  552.05          0.048693   2023-08-10  2023-08-10
2         2  Amrt  560.61          0.049448   2023-07-10  2023-07-10
3         2  Amrt  552.05          0.048693   2023-08-10  2023-08-10
```