# How to explode pandas dataframe columns and create new column with the key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-explode

I have pandas daraframe where I have multiple column which has list of dictionary. Ex:

```
col1  col2   combine_col1                 combine_col2
val1  val2   [{'x1':'v1','x2':'v2'}]      [{'x3':'v3','x4':'v4','x5':'v5'}]
val11 val22  [{'x1':'v11','x2':'v22'}]    [{'x3':'v33','x4':'v44','x5':'v55'}]
```

Inside the combined column the number of keys and their name I don't know.It can be anything.

I want to explode those specific columns which has list of dict and get all the keys as new columns. For this example the output dataframe column names should be `col1, col2, x1, x2,x3,x4,x5`. Currently I am hardcoding the combine cols and then doing explode operation. But I want that to happen automatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/split-explode-a-column-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-with-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only one element lists like in sample data use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) with `str[0]` for select them:

```
import ast

cols = ['combine_col1','combine_col2']

#if necessary
#df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(ast.literal_eval)

df1 = (df.drop(cols, axis=1)
         .join(pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(df[x].str[0]) for x in cols], axis=1)))
print (df1)
    col1   col2   x1   x2   x3   x4   x5
0   val1   val2   v1   v2   v3   v4   v5
1  val11  val22  v11  v22  v33  v44  v55
```

EDIT: Solution with append `prefix`:

```
df1 = (df.drop(cols, axis=1)
         .join(pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(df[x].str[0]).add_prefix(f'{x}.') 
                          for x in cols], axis=1)))
print (df1)
    col1   col2 combine_col1.x1 combine_col1.x2 combine_col2.x3  \
0   val1   val2              v1              v2              v3   
1  val11  val22             v11             v22             v33   

  combine_col2.x4 combine_col2.x5  
0              v4              v5  
1             v44             v55
```

If possible multiple values per lists use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
df1 = (df.drop(cols, axis=1)
         .join(pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(df[x].explode()) for x in cols], axis=1)))
```

---

```
df1 = (df.drop(cols, axis=1)
         .join(pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(df[x].explode()).add_prefix(f'{x}.') 
                          for x in cols], axis=1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If additionally I want to add the actual column name as prefix.Example: x1 will be combine_col1.x1 then can I do in one should without doing column rename multiple times?

Comment: @Dcook - in first or second solution?

Comment: @Dcook - Added to solution.

Comment: second solution

Comment: Sometime this gives error: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'values'`. How can I avoid this error if there any decimal or int value?I am using this but still getting error`df1 = (df.drop(cols, axis=1)
.join(pd.concat(
    [pd.json_normalize(df[x].explode(), errors='ignore').applymap(
        lambda x: [x] if isinstance(x, (int, float)) else x).add_prefix(f'{x}.') for x in
     cols],
    axis=1)))`