# Explode function not working on simple python dataframe

Tags: python, series, explode

I am having an issue with the explode function. I have a 2 column dataframe:

| pub_id | category_for |
| --- | --- |
| pub.1155807502 | [{'id': '80003', 'name': '32 Biomedical and Clinical Sciences'}, {'id': '80045', 'name': '3202 Clinical Sciences'}] |
| pub.1153826092 | [{'id': '80003', 'name': '32 Biomedical and Clinical Sciences'}, {'id': '80232', 'name': '5202 Biological Psychology'}, {'id': '80045', 'name': '3202 Clinical Sciences'}, {'id': '80052', 'name': '3209 Neurosciences'}, {'id': '80023', 'name': '52 Psychology'}] |
| pub.1145064359 | [{'id': '80003', 'name': '32 Biomedical and Clinical Sciences'}, {'id': '80052', 'name': '3209 Neurosciences'}, {'id': '80045', 'name': '3202 Clinical Sciences'}] |
| pub.1145747691 | [{'id': '80003', 'name': '32 Biomedical and Clinical Sciences'}, {'id': '80052', 'name': '3209 Neurosciences'}, {'id': '80045', 'name': '3202 Clinical Sciences'}] |
| pub.1144315107 | [{'id': '80003', 'name': '32 Biomedical and Clinical Sciences'}, {'id': '80232', 'name': '5202 Biological Psychology'}, {'id': '80045', 'name': '3202 Clinical Sciences'}, {'id': '80052', 'name': '3209 Neurosciences'}, {'id': '80023', 'name': '52 Psychology'}] |

And I want to "explode" the "category_for" column to obtain something like this:

| pub_id | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pub.1155807502 | 80003 | 32 Biomedical and Clinical Sciences |
| pub.1155807502 | 80045 | 3202 Clinical Sciences |
| pub.1153826092 | 80003 | 32 Biomedical and Clinical Sciences |
| pub.1153826092 | 80232 | 5202 Biological Psychology |
| pub.1153826092 | 80045 | 3202 Clinical Sciences |
| pub.1153826092 | 80052 | 3209 Neurosciences |
| pub.1153826092 | 80023 | 52 Psychology |

I tried

```
df = df.explode('category_for') 
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("category_for").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

but nothing happens at the "explode" step.

I also tried:

```
df.set_index('pub_id')['category_for'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0:'category_for'})
```

but again without success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/split-explode-a-column-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-with-pandas)

Comment: No that's not working, it returns one column only...

Comment: Could it be that the values in your column `"category_for"` are string representations of lists with dicts, rather than actual lists? If so, you can use `import ast` and `df['category_for'] = df['category_for'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))` to get proper lists. Afterwards, applying your first attempt (with `explode`) should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of dicts in the `category_for` column are probably stored as strings. You can check if that's the case with the following.

```py
type(df.category_for[0])
>>> str
```

You can convert the type of the items by applying the `literal_eval` function.

```py
from ast import literal_eval

# convert the column items from str to list of dicts
df.loc[:, "category_for"] = df.loc[:, "category_for"].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x))
```

Finally, you can use `explode`, and concatenate with the `pub_id` column.

```py
df = df.explode("category_for", ignore_index=True)

df_result = pd.concat([df.pub_id, df.category_for.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```