# Create DataFrame from a DataFrame having list of Dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the Output DataFrame, but unable to decide the approach for unpacking the data and converting to DataFrame.

Input DataFrame

```
stats
[{'city':None, 'last_time': 1234567}]
[]
[{'city':'Seattle', 'last_time': 45678999876}]
```

Expected Output

```
city       last_time
None       1234567
NA         NA
Seattle    45678999876
```

Code Tried

```
data = pd.DataFrame(Data)
data = pd.DataFrame(data["stats"])
```

Any guidance/help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate without a doubt: I tried [Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/split-explode-a-column-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-with-pandas) `df[0].apply(pd.Series)` is exactly what you need and is the most upvoted answer to this question

Comment: Did you have difficulty making a dataframe out of the list of dictionaries in the first place? You presented your input data as a `dataframe`

Comment: Clearly instanciating `Data` would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your construction fails because of the `NaN`s.

Here is a possible fix with [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)/[`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html):

```
out = df["stats"].str[0].apply(pd.Series).drop(0, axis=1)
```

Or this one :

```
stats = df["stats"].str[0]
templ = dict.fromkeys(["city", "last_time"])

out = stats.where(stats.notnull(), templ).apply(pd.Series)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

      city      last_time
0      NaN     1234567.00
1     None            NaN
2  Seattle 45678999876.00

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Used input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "stats": [
            [{"city": None, "last_time": 1234567}],
            [],
            [{"city": "Seattle", "last_time": 45678999876}]]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

*If this is the answer you seek:*

**Input dataframe**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['stats'],
                  data = [[{'city':None, 'last_time': 1234567}],
                          [],
                          [{'city':'Seattle', 'last_time': 45678999876}]])
df
                                           stats
0           {'city': None, 'last_time': 1234567}
1                                           None
2  {'city': 'Seattle', 'last_time': 45678999876}
```

**Output dataframe**
Split dictionaries to columns, one new column per key:

```
df['stats'].apply(pd.Series)

      city     last_time
0      NaN  1.234567e+06
1      NaN           NaN
2  Seattle  4.567900e+10
```

*...then it is a duplicate of [Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38231591/12846804)*

As you can observe, this functions also in presence of gaps in your input dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "stats": [
        [{'city': None, 'last_time': 1234567}],
        [],
        [{'city': 'Seattle', 'last_time': 45678999876}]
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

output_data = []

for row in df['stats']:
    if not row:
        output_data.append({'city': 'NA', 'last_time': 'NA'})
    else:
        output_data.append({'city': row[0]['city'], 'last_time': row[0]['last_time']})
output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_data)
print(output_df)
```

Output:

```
      city    last_time
0     None      1234567
1       NA           NA
2  Seattle  45678999876
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
>>> pd.json_normalize(df['stats'].explode())

      city     last_time
0     None  1.234567e+06
1      NaN           NaN
2  Seattle  4.567900e+10
```

`apply(pd.Series)` can be slow:

```
>>> %timeit pd.json_normalize(df['stats'].explode())
269 µs ± 17.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

>>> %timeit df["stats"].str[0].apply(pd.Series)
959 µs ± 5.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Input data is the same than @Timeless