# Split json data into multiple column with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have json with nested structure and each json has different keys.

```
                                 json_field
1 {"1": {"id": 1, "value": "value1"}, "2": {"id": 2, "value": "value2"}}
2 {"1": {"id": 1, "value": "value1"}, "3": {"id": 3, "value": "value3"}}
3 {"3": {"id": 3, "value": "value3"}, "4": {"id": 4, "value": "value4"}}
```

I want to split each key into separate field

```
   field1     field2     field3     field4
1  value1     value2       -           -
2  value1        -       value3        -
3     -          -       value3     value4
```

For now i have dict with "header:id" mapping

```
headers_mapping = {"field1": 1, "field2": 2, "field3": 3, "field4": 4}
```

Then i iterate through this dict and find values for each header in each row

```
for header, field_id in headers_mapping.items():
    df[header] = df.apply(
        lambda x: (
            x["json_field"][str(field_id)].get("value", "")
            if x["json_field"].get(str(field_id)) is not None
            else "-"
        ),
        axis=1
    )
df.drop("json_field", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Please advise a more effective way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible solutions. Generally though, you'll probably want to:

1. Not loop over fields; instead let Pandas split the fields for you
2. Use an actual [missing value](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing)

   - But later if you want to represent it differently, you can do that, e.g. using the `na_rep` parameter to [`df.style.format`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html)

For the first step, you can look at [Split / Explode a column of dictionaries into separate columns with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38231591/4518341). I'll use [Lech Birek's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55355928/4518341) ([`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)) then drop the "id" columns and rename the "value" columns.

```
headers_mapping = {'1': 'field1', '2': 'field2', '3': 'field3', '4': 'field4'}
(
    pd.json_normalize(df['json_field'])
    .filter(like='value')
    .rename(columns=lambda label: headers_mapping[label.rstrip('.value')])
)
```

```
   field1  field2  field3  field4
0  value1  value2     NaN     NaN
1  value1     NaN  value3     NaN
2     NaN     NaN  value3  value4
```

If you also need to sort the columns, tack this on at the end:

```
.reindex(columns=headers_mapping.values())
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew about `json_normalize`. `filter`, `rename` and `reindex` are game changers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
import json

# apply `json.loads` if necessary
df["json_field"] = df["json_field"].apply(json.loads)

data = []
for d in df["json_field"]:
    dct = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        dct[f"field{k}"] = v["value"]
    data.append(dct)

out = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   field1  field2  field3  field4
0  value1  value2     NaN     NaN
1  value1     NaN  value3     NaN
2     NaN     NaN  value3  value4
```

Comment: FWIW, you can turn it into a comp: `data = [{f"field{k}": v["value"] for k, v in d.items()} for d in df["json_field"]]`

Answer (score 0):

Proposed code:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {"json_field": {"1": {"id": 1, "value": "value1"}, "2": {"id": 2, "value": "value2"}}},
    {"json_field": {"1": {"id": 1, "value": "value1"}, "3": {"id": 3, "value": "value3"}}},
    {"json_field": {"3": {"id": 3, "value": "value3"}, "4": {"id": 4, "value": "value4"}}}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

headers_mapping = {"field1": 1, "field2": 2, "field3": 3, "field4": 4}

for header, field_id in headers_mapping.items():
    # Access values in dictionaries
    df[header] = df["json_field"].apply(lambda row: row.get(str(field_id), {}).get("value", "-"))

df.drop("json_field", axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

```
   field1  field2  field3  field4
0  value1  value2       -       -
1  value1       -  value3       -
2       -       -  value3  value4
```

Code explanation:

`row` sample :

```
{'1': {'id': 1, 'value': 'value1'}, '2': {'id': 2, 'value': 'value2'}}
```

`row` is a dict so this is how we access JSON values with dict method `get()` (note we add default `{}` to prevent errors non-existing values return), for instance :

```
>>> row.get('1', {})
{'id': 1, 'value': 'value1'}
>>> row.get('1', {}).get("value", "-")  # default is '-'
'value1'
```