# Column with lists of dicts to new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a `column2` which for each row have a list of dicts.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{"id":1,
         "column1":123, 
         "column2":[{"a":1}, {"b":"X"}, {"c":'2023-01-16'}]}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   # id  column1                                      column2
   # 1      123  [{'a': 1}, {'b': 'X'}, {'c': '2023-01-16'}]
```

I'm trying to create three new columns from the dicts to create:

```
#id   column1   a   b   c
# 1   123       1   X   2023-01-16
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/split-explode-a-column-of-dictionaries-into-separate-columns-with-pandas):

```
df = df.explode(column="column2")
#    column1              column2
# 0      123             {'a': 1}
# 0      123           {'b': 'X'}
# 0      123  {'c': '2023-01-16'}
df["column2"].apply(pd.Series)
#           0           1                    2
# 0  {'a': 1}  {'b': 'X'}  {'c': '2023-01-16'}
```

But I cant get it to work the way I want.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine a merge of the dictionaries (e.g. with [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap)) and [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
from collections import ChainMap

df = df.join(pd.json_normalize([dict(ChainMap(*l)) for l in df.pop('column2')]))

# or
# df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('column2')
#                                  .map(lambda x: dict(ChainMap(*x)))))
```

Output:

```
   id  column1           c  b  a
0   1      123  2023-01-16  X  1
```